# How can I determine a user's locale within the browser?

Tags: javascript, flash, browser, localization

I have a website (Flash) localized into a dozen of languages and I want to auto-define a default value depending on the user's browser settings in order to minimize the steps to access the content.

FYI, I cannot use server scripts due to proxy restrictions, so I guess JavaScript or ActionScript would be appropriate to solve the problem.

**Questions:**

1. What would be the best method to 'guess' the user's locale?
2. Are there any existing simple classes/functions that could help me out (no complex localization bundles)? Especially to reduce all possible languages to a smaller number (the translations I have) in a smart way.
3. To which point can I trust such a solution?
4. Any other workarounds or suggestions?

Comment: THe only way a browser can share meta data about its user and the request is via URLs and headers. Grab Firefox and take a peek at the headers being sent when a request is made. Its quite interesting to examine typical request and response headers.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

The proper way is to look at the HTTP [Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) header sent to the server. This contains the ordered, weighted list of languages the user has configured their browser to prefer.

Unfortunately this header is not available for reading inside JavaScript; all you get is [`navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language), which tells you what localised version of the web browser was installed. This is not necessarily the same thing as the user's preferred language(s). On IE you instead get `systemLanguage` (OS installed language), `browserLanguage` (same as `language`) and `userLanguage` (user configured OS region), which are all similarly unhelpful.

If I had to choose between those properties, I'd sniff for `userLanguage` first, falling back to `language` and only after that (if those didn't match any available language) looking at `browserLanguage` and finally `systemLanguage`.

If you can put a server-side script somewhere else on the net that simply reads the Accept-Language header and spits it back out as a JavaScript file with the header value in the string, eg.:

```
var acceptLanguage= 'en-gb,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.3';
```

then you could include a <script src> pointing at that external service in the HTML, and use JavaScript to parse the language header. I don't know of any existing library code to do this, though, since Accept-Language parsing is almost always done on the server side.

Whatever you end up doing, you certainly need a user override because it will always guess wrong for some people. Often it's easiest to put the language setting in the URL (eg. http​://www.example.com/en/site vs http​://www.example.com/de/site), and let the user click links between the two. Sometimes you do want a single URL for both language versions, in which case you have to store the setting in cookies, but this may confuse user agents with no support for cookies and search engines.

Comment: From MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/languages "The Accept-Language HTTP header in every HTTP request from the user's browser uses the same value for the navigator.languages property except for the extra qvalues (quality values) field (e.g. en-US;q=0.8)."

Comment: Update: There is now (2020) an experimental feature supported by all modern browsers that returns an array of language preference: `navigator.languages  //["en-US", "zh-CN", "ja-JP"]` This should work on at least 95% of browsers in 2020.

Comment: `navigator.languages`, according to both [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/languages) and [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_navigatorlanguage_languages), is now available in all major browsers - try the tiny (~200 bytes) [navigator-languages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/navigator-languages) package for the most modern and backwards-compatible approach.

Comment: @bora89 Because the accepted answer is from 2009 i.e. 13 years ago. Implementations and documentation tends to change in that span of time you know...

Answer (score 168):

On Chrome and Firefox 32+, [`Navigator.languages`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/languages) contains an array of locales in order of user preference, and is more accurate than `navigator.language`, however, to make it backward-compatible (Tested Chrome / IE / Firefox / Safari), then use this:

```js
function getLang() {
  if (navigator.languages != undefined) 
    return navigator.languages[0]; 
  return navigator.language;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for IE9 and IE10.  For them, you have to examine navigator.browserLanguage instead.

Comment: OneLiner : `function getLang(){ return ( navigator.language || navigator.languages[0] ); }`

Comment: @ChStark Shouldn't it be `return navigator.languages[0] || navigator.language;`?

Comment: Also, the *correct* "one-liner" would look like this: `return (navigator.languages && navigator.languages.length) ? navigator.languages[0] : navigator.language;`. Otherwise you get an exception if `navigator.languages` is undefined or empty.

Comment: For an even more compact version
`const getLang = () => navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage || ( navigator.languages || [ "en" ] ) [ 0 ]`

Comment: The value of `navigator.language` is the first element of `navigator.languages`, as per [Mozilla specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/languages).

So `navigator.language` is `navigator.languages[0]`.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. From the same page: "In Chrome, navigator.language is the language of the browser UI, and is not guaranteed to be equal to navigator.languages[0]."

Comment: This is not working. In my case, this is returning ['en-US', 'en', 'fr-FR', 'fr'] instead of ['fr-FR', 'fr', 'en-US', 'en'], so the determined user locale is wrong.

Answer (score 58):

[This article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/detect-foreign-language-support-using-javascript/) suggests the following properties of the browser's **navigator** object:

- `navigator.language` (Netscape - Browser Localization)
- `navigator.browserLanguage` (IE-Specific - Browser Localized Language)
- `navigator.systemLanguage` (IE-Specific - Windows OS - Localized Language)
- `navigator.userLanguage`

Roll these into a javascript function and you should be able to guess the right language, in most circumstances. Be sure to degrade gracefully, so have a div containing your language choice links, so that if there is no javascript or the method doesn't work, the user can still decide. If it does work, just hide the div.

The only problem with doing this on the client side is that either you serve up *all* the languages to the client, or you have to wait until the script has run and detected the language before requesting the right version. Perhaps serving up the most popular language version as a default would irritate the fewest people.

Edit: I'd second Ivan's cookie suggestion, but make sure the user can always change the language later; not everyone prefers the language their browser defaults to.

Comment: Thanks Phil for your suggestions. Regarding the article, it's 6 years old ... not sure we can rely on it ?

Comment: I suspect that modern browsers all support navigator.language. My browser (FF3 on Ubuntu 8.10) reports 'en-GB'. If someone is still using IE6 - around 20% of people - then it's worth allowing for that. IE6 appeared 8 years ago.

Comment: IE 8 doesn't support navigator.language. Perhaps IE 9 will?

Answer (score 56):

There's a difference between the user's preferred languages and the system/browser locale.

A user can configure preferred languages in the browser, and these will be used for `navigator.language(s)`, and used when requesting resources from a server, to request content according to a list of language priorities.

However, the browser locale will decide how to render number, date, time and currency. This setting is likely the highest ranking language, but there is no guarantee. On Mac and Linux, the locale is decided by the system regardless of the user language preferences. On Windows is can be elected among the languages in the preferred list on Chrome.

By using Intl (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl), developers can override/set the locale to use to render these things, but there are elements that cannot be overridden, such as the `<input type="date">` format.

To properly extract this language, the only way I've found is:

`(new Intl.NumberFormat()).resolvedOptions().locale`

(`Intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions().locale` also seems to work)

This will create a new NumberFormat instance for the default locale and then reading back the locale of those resolved options.

Comment: Very important answer to add to the picture. For example, in my Chromium `navigator.language` gives de-DE (which is my system setting), however all dates and number are formatted en-US (which is my browser setting), which this answer correctly determines.

Comment: Yeah I want to thank you as well for this answer. At a quick glance it felt like the question was "How can I determine a users Locale within the browser" and the answers were all of the type "Here's how you find the users preferred language instead, hope that helps".

Comment: Do they return the same? `Intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions().locale` and `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale`

Answer (score 55):

Combining the multiple ways browsers are using to store the user's language, you get this function:

```
const getNavigatorLanguage = () => {
  if (navigator.languages && navigator.languages.length) {
    return navigator.languages[0];
  } else {
    return navigator.userLanguage || navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage || 'en';
  }
}
```

We first check the `navigator.languages` array for its first element.
Then we get either `navigator.userLanguage` or `navigator.language`.
If this fails we get `navigator.browserLanguage`.
Finally, we set it to `'en'` if everything else failed.

---

**And here's the sexy one-liner:**

```
const getNavigatorLanguage = () => (navigator.languages && navigator.languages.length) ? navigator.languages[0] : navigator.userLanguage || navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage || 'en';
```

Comment: there is apparently also something as `navigator.userLanguage` (for IE). You could add that to make it complete :)

Comment: Why not simply `navigator.languages[0] || navigator.userLanguage || navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage || 'en'` ?

Comment: @Curse Because `navigator.languages` can be `undefined`

Comment: @Zenoo Do you know on which browsers ?

Comment: `(navigator.languages || [])[0] || navigator.userLanguage || navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage || 'en'`

Answer (score 26):

I used all the answers and created a single line solution:

```
const getLanguage = () => navigator.userLanguage || (navigator.languages && navigator.languages.length && navigator.languages[0]) || navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage || navigator.systemLanguage || 'en';

console.log(getLanguage());
```

Comment: What is the gist of it? What is the idea? Why was it combined exactly this and not some other way? What is thinking behind it?

Answer (score 7):

I did a bit of research regarding this & I have summarised my findings so far in below table

[image]

So the recommended solution is to write a a server side script to parse the `Accept-Language` header & pass it to client for setting the language of the website. It's weird that why the server would be needed to detect the language preference of client but that's how it is as of now There are other various hacks available to detect the language but reading the `Accept-Language` header is the recommended solution as per my understanding.

Comment: That is unreadable. Opening it in a separate tab is only slightly better.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to get the language from the document should might be your first port of call, then falling back to other means as often people will want their JS language to match the document language.

HTML5:

`document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('lang')`

Legacy:

`document.querySelector('meta[http-equiv=content-language]').getAttribute('content')`

No real source is necessarily 100% reliable as people can simply put in the wrong language.

There are language detection libraries that might let you determine the language by content.

Answer (score 1):

I am porting this from *[JavaScript for detecting browser language preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)*

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference/42649975#42649975).

I've just come up with this. It combines newer JS [destructuring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Parallel_assignment) syntax with a few standard operations to retrieve the language and locale.

```
var [lang, locale] = (
    (
        (
            navigator.userLanguage || navigator.language
        ).replace(
            '-', '_'
        )
    ).toLowerCase()
).split('_');
```

I'd also recommend testing this and combining with other answers, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/52112155/1548557 which seems like a more robust way to get the language. We also have null coalesce `??` so perhaps `||` is not the best way. I imagine this to be something like

```
var [lang, locale] = (
    (
        getBrowserLanguage()
            .replace('-', '_')
    ).toLowerCase()
).split('_');
```

Note that I've not mandated a default value for lang or locale, which you could do. The world is so anglo-centric. I'd pick English for this, but I didn't feel like it would benefit anyone me coding that in. I *also* did not call `getBrowserLanguage` `getNavigatorLanguage`, which was deliberate. Maybe you use navigator, but maybe something else comes up in future. This really is a preference.

Answer (score -1):

You said your website has Flash, then, as another option, you can get operation system's language with [`flash.system.Capabilities.language`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html)— see [How to determine OS language within browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894488/is-there-anyway-to-detect-os-language-using-javascript/30351342#30351342) to *guess* an operation system locale.

Comment: Flash is now dead