# Get Locale Short Date Format using javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

Is there anyway we can know using JavaScript the Short Date Format used in the Control Panel -> Regional and Language Settings?

I know the using the combination of following we can get the Locale Long Name format

```
toString()
toLocaleString()
toLocaleDateString()
toLocaleTimeString()
```

But there is no direct function in JavaScript like `toLocaleShortDateString()`.

Are there any scripts available to find out what the user setting is?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure i understand: you mean hot to get the format itself? becuase the "missing function" name you give is misleading (toLocaleShortDateString), maybe something like "getLocaleShortDateFormat"?

Comment: I found the answers to this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673905/best-way-to-determine-users-locale-within-browser) more helpful for my purposes since I just want to provide a half-decent default for which the clientside-only solutions presented there are useful.

Answer (score 336):

```js
function getLocaleDateString() {
  const formats = {
    "af-ZA": "yyyy/MM/dd",
    "am-ET": "d/M/yyyy",
    "ar-AE": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "ar-BH": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "ar-DZ": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "ar-EG": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "ar-IQ": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "ar-JO": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "ar-KW": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "ar-LB": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "ar-LY": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "ar-MA": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "ar-OM": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "ar-QA": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "ar-SA": "dd/MM/yy",
    "ar-SY": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "ar-TN": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "ar-YE": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "arn-CL": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "as-IN": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "az-Cyrl-AZ": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "az-Latn-AZ": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "ba-RU": "dd.MM.yy",
    "be-BY": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "bg-BG": "dd.M.yyyy",
    "bn-BD": "dd-MM-yy",
    "bn-IN": "dd-MM-yy",
    "bo-CN": "yyyy/M/d",
    "br-FR": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "bs-Cyrl-BA": "d.M.yyyy",
    "bs-Latn-BA": "d.M.yyyy",
    "ca-ES": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "co-FR": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "cs-CZ": "d.M.yyyy",
    "cy-GB": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "da-DK": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "de-AT": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "de-CH": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "de-DE": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "de-LI": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "de-LU": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "dsb-DE": "d. M. yyyy",
    "dv-MV": "dd/MM/yy",
    "el-GR": "d/M/yyyy",
    "en-029": "MM/dd/yyyy",
    "en-AU": "d/MM/yyyy",
    "en-BZ": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "en-CA": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "en-GB": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "en-IE": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "en-IN": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "en-JM": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "en-MY": "d/M/yyyy",
    "en-NZ": "d/MM/yyyy",
    "en-PH": "M/d/yyyy",
    "en-SG": "d/M/yyyy",
    "en-TT": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "en-US": "M/d/yyyy",
    "en-ZA": "yyyy/MM/dd",
    "en-ZW": "M/d/yyyy",
    "es-AR": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-BO": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-CL": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "es-CO": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-CR": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-DO": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-EC": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-ES": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-GT": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-HN": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-MX": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-NI": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-PA": "MM/dd/yyyy",
    "es-PE": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-PR": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-PY": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-SV": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-US": "M/d/yyyy",
    "es-UY": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "es-VE": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "et-EE": "d.MM.yyyy",
    "eu-ES": "yyyy/MM/dd",
    "fa-IR": "MM/dd/yyyy",
    "fi-FI": "d.M.yyyy",
    "fil-PH": "M/d/yyyy",
    "fo-FO": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "fr-BE": "d/MM/yyyy",
    "fr-CA": "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "fr-CH": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "fr-FR": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "fr-LU": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "fr-MC": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "fy-NL": "d-M-yyyy",
    "ga-IE": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "gd-GB": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "gl-ES": "dd/MM/yy",
    "gsw-FR": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "gu-IN": "dd-MM-yy",
    "ha-Latn-NG": "d/M/yyyy",
    "he-IL": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "hi-IN": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "hr-BA": "d.M.yyyy.",
    "hr-HR": "d.M.yyyy",
    "hsb-DE": "d. M. yyyy",
    "hu-HU": "yyyy. MM. dd.",
    "hy-AM": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "id-ID": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "ig-NG": "d/M/yyyy",
    "ii-CN": "yyyy/M/d",
    "is-IS": "d.M.yyyy",
    "it-CH": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "it-IT": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "iu-Cans-CA": "d/M/yyyy",
    "iu-Latn-CA": "d/MM/yyyy",
    "ja-JP": "yyyy/MM/dd",
    "ka-GE": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "kk-KZ": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "kl-GL": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "km-KH": "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "kn-IN": "dd-MM-yy",
    "ko-KR": "yyyy. MM. dd",
    "kok-IN": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "ky-KG": "dd.MM.yy",
    "lb-LU": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "lo-LA": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "lt-LT": "yyyy.MM.dd",
    "lv-LV": "yyyy.MM.dd.",
    "mi-NZ": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "mk-MK": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "ml-IN": "dd-MM-yy",
    "mn-MN": "yy.MM.dd",
    "mn-Mong-CN": "yyyy/M/d",
    "moh-CA": "M/d/yyyy",
    "mr-IN": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "ms-BN": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "ms-MY": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "mt-MT": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "nb-NO": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "ne-NP": "M/d/yyyy",
    "nl-BE": "d/MM/yyyy",
    "nl-NL": "d-M-yyyy",
    "nn-NO": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "nso-ZA": "yyyy/MM/dd",
    "oc-FR": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "or-IN": "dd-MM-yy",
    "pa-IN": "dd-MM-yy",
    "pl-PL": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "prs-AF": "dd/MM/yy",
    "ps-AF": "dd/MM/yy",
    "pt-BR": "d/M/yyyy",
    "pt-PT": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "qut-GT": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "quz-BO": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "quz-EC": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "quz-PE": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "rm-CH": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "ro-RO": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "ru-RU": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "rw-RW": "M/d/yyyy",
    "sa-IN": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "sah-RU": "MM.dd.yyyy",
    "se-FI": "d.M.yyyy",
    "se-NO": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "se-SE": "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "si-LK": "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "sk-SK": "d. M. yyyy",
    "sl-SI": "d.M.yyyy",
    "sma-NO": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "sma-SE": "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "smj-NO": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "smj-SE": "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "smn-FI": "d.M.yyyy",
    "sms-FI": "d.M.yyyy",
    "sq-AL": "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "sr-Cyrl-BA": "d.M.yyyy",
    "sr-Cyrl-CS": "d.M.yyyy",
    "sr-Cyrl-ME": "d.M.yyyy",
    "sr-Cyrl-RS": "d.M.yyyy",
    "sr-Latn-BA": "d.M.yyyy",
    "sr-Latn-CS": "d.M.yyyy",
    "sr-Latn-ME": "d.M.yyyy",
    "sr-Latn-RS": "d.M.yyyy",
    "sv-FI": "d.M.yyyy",
    "sv-SE": "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "sw-KE": "M/d/yyyy",
    "syr-SY": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "ta-IN": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "te-IN": "dd-MM-yy",
    "tg-Cyrl-TJ": "dd.MM.yy",
    "th-TH": "d/M/yyyy",
    "tk-TM": "dd.MM.yy",
    "tn-ZA": "yyyy/MM/dd",
    "tr-TR": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "tt-RU": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "tzm-Latn-DZ": "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "ug-CN": "yyyy-M-d",
    "uk-UA": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "ur-PK": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "uz-Cyrl-UZ": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "uz-Latn-UZ": "dd/MM yyyy",
    "vi-VN": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "wo-SN": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "xh-ZA": "yyyy/MM/dd",
    "yo-NG": "d/M/yyyy",
    "zh-CN": "yyyy/M/d",
    "zh-HK": "d/M/yyyy",
    "zh-MO": "d/M/yyyy",
    "zh-SG": "d/M/yyyy",
    "zh-TW": "yyyy/M/d",
    "zu-ZA": "yyyy/MM/dd",
  };

  return formats[navigator.language] || "dd/MM/yyyy";
}
console.log(navigator.language,getLocaleDateString());
```

Comment: This needs to be case insensitive, my Safari returns en-us.

Comment: Local format can be different (custom), depends on OS

Comment: Can I get the source of this list?

Comment: @iegik's answer is has the 2016 answer: `(new Intl.DateTimeFormat()).resolved.pattern`.

Comment: @Chexpir The Unicode CLDR project is the ultimate source of this list, and https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-dates-modern is a slightly more consumable version of it. Still a far cry from the above data. :)

Comment: @PaulIrish `(new Intl.DateTimeFormat()).resolved.pattern` appears to be defunct. I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pattern' of undefined` and I saw some chromium bug about removing that. `.resolvedOptions()` works, but excludes the pattern.

Comment: Hello, guys I just was wondering if this follows the DateTimeFormat in Java. Any idea how to implement it ? Without do it manually

Comment: `"ko-KR" : "yyyy-MM-dd",` this is not valid any more, it's now `yyyy. MM. dd`

Comment: `"pl-PL"` is also invalid. it is now `dd.MM.yyyy`

Comment: a more precise locale with this code:  

`const locale = new Intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions().locale`
instead of `navigator.language`. Otherwise works like a charm.

Comment: As the number of comments here show, anything that relies on a hard-coded list will quickly become outdated. Other programmatic solutions are more reliable.

Comment: @Kip what is your proposal for a programmatic solution? I have not found a good way to get a short-date with all 4 digits for year. For example the Angular shortDate pre-defined format, uses 2 digit years.

Comment: I would like the option to parse them in the exact format you want, isn't this possible?

Comment: This gives format based on the browser language. Is there any way to get the format based on windows language, since browser and OS languages may be different.

Answer (score 161):

I think this is the best way to do it...

```js
    var date = new Date();

    var options = {
        weekday: "short",
        year: "numeric",
        month: "2-digit",
        day: "numeric"
    };

console.log(
    date.toLocaleDateString("en", options) //en is language option, you may specify..
);
```

More Options and their examples....

```
Option          Values          Sample output
----------------------------------------------------
weekday         'narrow'        'M'
                'short'         'Mon'
                'long'          'Monday'

year            '2-digit'       '01'
                'numeric'       '2001'

month           '2-digit'       '01'
                'numeric'       '1'
                'narrow'        'J'
                'short'         'Jan'
                'long'          'January'

day             '2-digit'       '01'
                'numeric'       '1'

hour            '2-digit'       '12 AM'
                'numeric'       '12 AM'

minute          '2-digit'       '0'
                'numeric'       '0'

second          '2-digit'       '0'
                'numeric'       '0'

timeZoneName    'short'         '1/1/2001 GMT+00:00'
                'long'          '1/1/2001 GMT+00:00'
```

Comment: Note that IE (as of 10) does not respect the options, and will return the month name whatever you specify.

Comment: In face FF latest version (25) exhibits the same behaviour; it seems only Chrome supports the options.

Comment: Safari also ignores options.

Comment: for anyone hitting this now support is much better.. chrome & firefox have both supported the options for some time , IE11 onwards supports..  Safari/ Webkit still doesn't

Comment: This is great info. It would be even better if you linked to a source for the options.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: Fantastic! finally a way to return dates with leading zeroes, without using external libraries! 10+

Comment: Better to replace `"en"` with `navigator.language`.  So, return/display `date.toLocaleDateString(navigator.language, options)`

Answer (score 16):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat):

> The Intl.DateTimeFormat object is a constructor for objects that enable language sensitive date and time formatting.

Example:

```js
var date = new Date(2014, 11, 31, 12, 30, 0);

var formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("ru");
console.log(formatter.format(date)); // 31.12.2014

var formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US");

console.log(formatter.format(date)); // 12/31/2014
```

The below StackSnippet will log the current date in your local format.

```js
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale).format(new Date()))
```

Answer (score 14):

I stumbled on this thread while trying to work out how to display a placeholder for a date picker field. Ultimately, I want to see a user-friendly format string based on the browser's locale (e.g. for `'en-AU'` I want to display `'dd/mm/yyyy'`).

It looks like over the years, there's been various ways to achieve bits and pieces of this. `new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-AU")).resolved.pattern` looks like it used to be fairly well supported, but this has now been removed [in favour of `formatToParts`](https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/21).

Using `formatToParts` to dice up a date into its constituent parts lets us extrapolate the pattern string - here's a basic function that I wrote to do exactly that:

```
/**
 * Get the date format pattern for the given locale. 
 * @example 
 *     getDateFormatPattern('en-AU');   // dd/mm/yyyy
 *     getDateFormatPattern('en-US');   // m/d/yyyy
 */
const getDateFormatPattern = (locale: string) => {
    const getPatternForPart = (part: Intl.DateTimeFormatPart) => {
        switch (part.type) {
            case 'day':
                return 'd'.repeat(part.value.length);
            case 'month':
                return 'm'.repeat(part.value.length);
            case 'year':
                return 'y'.repeat(part.value.length);
            case 'literal':
                return part.value;
            default:
                console.log('Unsupported date part', part);
                return '';
        }
    };

    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale).formatToParts(new Date('2021-01-01'))
        .map(getPatternForPart)
        .join('');
};
```

Answer (score 13):

```
function getLocaleShortDateString(d)
{
    var f={"ar-SA":"dd/MM/yy","bg-BG":"dd.M.yyyy","ca-ES":"dd/MM/yyyy","zh-TW":"yyyy/M/d","cs-CZ":"d.M.yyyy","da-DK":"dd-MM-yyyy","de-DE":"dd.MM.yyyy","el-GR":"d/M/yyyy","en-US":"M/d/yyyy","fi-FI":"d.M.yyyy","fr-FR":"dd/MM/yyyy","he-IL":"dd/MM/yyyy","hu-HU":"yyyy. MM. dd.","is-IS":"d.M.yyyy","it-IT":"dd/MM/yyyy","ja-JP":"yyyy/MM/dd","ko-KR":"yyyy-MM-dd","nl-NL":"d-M-yyyy","nb-NO":"dd.MM.yyyy","pl-PL":"yyyy-MM-dd","pt-BR":"d/M/yyyy","ro-RO":"dd.MM.yyyy","ru-RU":"dd.MM.yyyy","hr-HR":"d.M.yyyy","sk-SK":"d. M. yyyy","sq-AL":"yyyy-MM-dd","sv-SE":"yyyy-MM-dd","th-TH":"d/M/yyyy","tr-TR":"dd.MM.yyyy","ur-PK":"dd/MM/yyyy","id-ID":"dd/MM/yyyy","uk-UA":"dd.MM.yyyy","be-BY":"dd.MM.yyyy","sl-SI":"d.M.yyyy","et-EE":"d.MM.yyyy","lv-LV":"yyyy.MM.dd.","lt-LT":"yyyy.MM.dd","fa-IR":"MM/dd/yyyy","vi-VN":"dd/MM/yyyy","hy-AM":"dd.MM.yyyy","az-Latn-AZ":"dd.MM.yyyy","eu-ES":"yyyy/MM/dd","mk-MK":"dd.MM.yyyy","af-ZA":"yyyy/MM/dd","ka-GE":"dd.MM.yyyy","fo-FO":"dd-MM-yyyy","hi-IN":"dd-MM-yyyy","ms-MY":"dd/MM/yyyy","kk-KZ":"dd.MM.yyyy","ky-KG":"dd.MM.yy","sw-KE":"M/d/yyyy","uz-Latn-UZ":"dd/MM yyyy","tt-RU":"dd.MM.yyyy","pa-IN":"dd-MM-yy","gu-IN":"dd-MM-yy","ta-IN":"dd-MM-yyyy","te-IN":"dd-MM-yy","kn-IN":"dd-MM-yy","mr-IN":"dd-MM-yyyy","sa-IN":"dd-MM-yyyy","mn-MN":"yy.MM.dd","gl-ES":"dd/MM/yy","kok-IN":"dd-MM-yyyy","syr-SY":"dd/MM/yyyy","dv-MV":"dd/MM/yy","ar-IQ":"dd/MM/yyyy","zh-CN":"yyyy/M/d","de-CH":"dd.MM.yyyy","en-GB":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-MX":"dd/MM/yyyy","fr-BE":"d/MM/yyyy","it-CH":"dd.MM.yyyy","nl-BE":"d/MM/yyyy","nn-NO":"dd.MM.yyyy","pt-PT":"dd-MM-yyyy","sr-Latn-CS":"d.M.yyyy","sv-FI":"d.M.yyyy","az-Cyrl-AZ":"dd.MM.yyyy","ms-BN":"dd/MM/yyyy","uz-Cyrl-UZ":"dd.MM.yyyy","ar-EG":"dd/MM/yyyy","zh-HK":"d/M/yyyy","de-AT":"dd.MM.yyyy","en-AU":"d/MM/yyyy","es-ES":"dd/MM/yyyy","fr-CA":"yyyy-MM-dd","sr-Cyrl-CS":"d.M.yyyy","ar-LY":"dd/MM/yyyy","zh-SG":"d/M/yyyy","de-LU":"dd.MM.yyyy","en-CA":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-GT":"dd/MM/yyyy","fr-CH":"dd.MM.yyyy","ar-DZ":"dd-MM-yyyy","zh-MO":"d/M/yyyy","de-LI":"dd.MM.yyyy","en-NZ":"d/MM/yyyy","es-CR":"dd/MM/yyyy","fr-LU":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-MA":"dd-MM-yyyy","en-IE":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-PA":"MM/dd/yyyy","fr-MC":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-TN":"dd-MM-yyyy","en-ZA":"yyyy/MM/dd","es-DO":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-OM":"dd/MM/yyyy","en-JM":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-VE":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-YE":"dd/MM/yyyy","en-029":"MM/dd/yyyy","es-CO":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-SY":"dd/MM/yyyy","en-BZ":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-PE":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-JO":"dd/MM/yyyy","en-TT":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-AR":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-LB":"dd/MM/yyyy","en-ZW":"M/d/yyyy","es-EC":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-KW":"dd/MM/yyyy","en-PH":"M/d/yyyy","es-CL":"dd-MM-yyyy","ar-AE":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-UY":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-BH":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-PY":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-QA":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-BO":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-SV":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-HN":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-NI":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-PR":"dd/MM/yyyy","am-ET":"d/M/yyyy","tzm-Latn-DZ":"dd-MM-yyyy","iu-Latn-CA":"d/MM/yyyy","sma-NO":"dd.MM.yyyy","mn-Mong-CN":"yyyy/M/d","gd-GB":"dd/MM/yyyy","en-MY":"d/M/yyyy","prs-AF":"dd/MM/yy","bn-BD":"dd-MM-yy","wo-SN":"dd/MM/yyyy","rw-RW":"M/d/yyyy","qut-GT":"dd/MM/yyyy","sah-RU":"MM.dd.yyyy","gsw-FR":"dd/MM/yyyy","co-FR":"dd/MM/yyyy","oc-FR":"dd/MM/yyyy","mi-NZ":"dd/MM/yyyy","ga-IE":"dd/MM/yyyy","se-SE":"yyyy-MM-dd","br-FR":"dd/MM/yyyy","smn-FI":"d.M.yyyy","moh-CA":"M/d/yyyy","arn-CL":"dd-MM-yyyy","ii-CN":"yyyy/M/d","dsb-DE":"d. M. yyyy","ig-NG":"d/M/yyyy","kl-GL":"dd-MM-yyyy","lb-LU":"dd/MM/yyyy","ba-RU":"dd.MM.yy","nso-ZA":"yyyy/MM/dd","quz-BO":"dd/MM/yyyy","yo-NG":"d/M/yyyy","ha-Latn-NG":"d/M/yyyy","fil-PH":"M/d/yyyy","ps-AF":"dd/MM/yy","fy-NL":"d-M-yyyy","ne-NP":"M/d/yyyy","se-NO":"dd.MM.yyyy","iu-Cans-CA":"d/M/yyyy","sr-Latn-RS":"d.M.yyyy","si-LK":"yyyy-MM-dd","sr-Cyrl-RS":"d.M.yyyy","lo-LA":"dd/MM/yyyy","km-KH":"yyyy-MM-dd","cy-GB":"dd/MM/yyyy","bo-CN":"yyyy/M/d","sms-FI":"d.M.yyyy","as-IN":"dd-MM-yyyy","ml-IN":"dd-MM-yy","en-IN":"dd-MM-yyyy","or-IN":"dd-MM-yy","bn-IN":"dd-MM-yy","tk-TM":"dd.MM.yy","bs-Latn-BA":"d.M.yyyy","mt-MT":"dd/MM/yyyy","sr-Cyrl-ME":"d.M.yyyy","se-FI":"d.M.yyyy","zu-ZA":"yyyy/MM/dd","xh-ZA":"yyyy/MM/dd","tn-ZA":"yyyy/MM/dd","hsb-DE":"d. M. yyyy","bs-Cyrl-BA":"d.M.yyyy","tg-Cyrl-TJ":"dd.MM.yy","sr-Latn-BA":"d.M.yyyy","smj-NO":"dd.MM.yyyy","rm-CH":"dd/MM/yyyy","smj-SE":"yyyy-MM-dd","quz-EC":"dd/MM/yyyy","quz-PE":"dd/MM/yyyy","hr-BA":"d.M.yyyy.","sr-Latn-ME":"d.M.yyyy","sma-SE":"yyyy-MM-dd","en-SG":"d/M/yyyy","ug-CN":"yyyy-M-d","sr-Cyrl-BA":"d.M.yyyy","es-US":"M/d/yyyy"};

    var l=navigator.language?navigator.language:navigator['userLanguage'],y=d.getFullYear(),m=d.getMonth()+1,d=d.getDate();
    f=(l in f)?f[l]:"MM/dd/yyyy";
    function z(s){s=''+s;return s.length>1?s:'0'+s;}
    f=f.replace(/yyyy/,y);f=f.replace(/yy/,String(y).substr(2));
    f=f.replace(/MM/,z(m));f=f.replace(/M/,m);
    f=f.replace(/dd/,z(d));f=f.replace(/d/,d);
    return f;
}
```

using:

```
shortedDate=getLocaleShortDateString(new Date(1992, 0, 7));
```

```js
shortedDate = getLocaleShortDateString(new Date(1992, 0, 7));
console.log(shortedDate);

function getLocaleShortDateString(d) {
  var f={"ar-SA":"dd/MM/yy","bg-BG":"dd.M.yyyy","ca-ES":"dd/MM/yyyy","zh-TW":"yyyy/M/d","cs-CZ":"d.M.yyyy","da-DK":"dd-MM-yyyy","de-DE":"dd.MM.yyyy","el-GR":"d/M/yyyy","en-US":"M/d/yyyy","fi-FI":"d.M.yyyy","fr-FR":"dd/MM/yyyy","he-IL":"dd/MM/yyyy","hu-HU":"yyyy. MM. dd.","is-IS":"d.M.yyyy","it-IT":"dd/MM/yyyy","ja-JP":"yyyy/MM/dd","ko-KR":"yyyy-MM-dd","nl-NL":"d-M-yyyy","nb-NO":"dd.MM.yyyy","pl-PL":"yyyy-MM-dd","pt-BR":"d/M/yyyy","ro-RO":"dd.MM.yyyy","ru-RU":"dd.MM.yyyy","hr-HR":"d.M.yyyy","sk-SK":"d. M. yyyy","sq-AL":"yyyy-MM-dd","sv-SE":"yyyy-MM-dd","th-TH":"d/M/yyyy","tr-TR":"dd.MM.yyyy","ur-PK":"dd/MM/yyyy","id-ID":"dd/MM/yyyy","uk-UA":"dd.MM.yyyy","be-BY":"dd.MM.yyyy","sl-SI":"d.M.yyyy","et-EE":"d.MM.yyyy","lv-LV":"yyyy.MM.dd.","lt-LT":"yyyy.MM.dd","fa-IR":"MM/dd/yyyy","vi-VN":"dd/MM/yyyy","hy-AM":"dd.MM.yyyy","az-Latn-AZ":"dd.MM.yyyy","eu-ES":"yyyy/MM/dd","mk-MK":"dd.MM.yyyy","af-ZA":"yyyy/MM/dd","ka-GE":"dd.MM.yyyy","fo-FO":"dd-MM-yyyy","hi-IN":"dd-MM-yyyy","ms-MY":"dd/MM/yyyy","kk-KZ":"dd.MM.yyyy","ky-KG":"dd.MM.yy","sw-KE":"M/d/yyyy","uz-Latn-UZ":"dd/MM yyyy","tt-RU":"dd.MM.yyyy","pa-IN":"dd-MM-yy","gu-IN":"dd-MM-yy","ta-IN":"dd-MM-yyyy","te-IN":"dd-MM-yy","kn-IN":"dd-MM-yy","mr-IN":"dd-MM-yyyy","sa-IN":"dd-MM-yyyy","mn-MN":"yy.MM.dd","gl-ES":"dd/MM/yy","kok-IN":"dd-MM-yyyy","syr-SY":"dd/MM/yyyy","dv-MV":"dd/MM/yy","ar-IQ":"dd/MM/yyyy","zh-CN":"yyyy/M/d","de-CH":"dd.MM.yyyy","en-GB":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-MX":"dd/MM/yyyy","fr-BE":"d/MM/yyyy","it-CH":"dd.MM.yyyy","nl-BE":"d/MM/yyyy","nn-NO":"dd.MM.yyyy","pt-PT":"dd-MM-yyyy","sr-Latn-CS":"d.M.yyyy","sv-FI":"d.M.yyyy","az-Cyrl-AZ":"dd.MM.yyyy","ms-BN":"dd/MM/yyyy","uz-Cyrl-UZ":"dd.MM.yyyy","ar-EG":"dd/MM/yyyy","zh-HK":"d/M/yyyy","de-AT":"dd.MM.yyyy","en-AU":"d/MM/yyyy","es-ES":"dd/MM/yyyy","fr-CA":"yyyy-MM-dd","sr-Cyrl-CS":"d.M.yyyy","ar-LY":"dd/MM/yyyy","zh-SG":"d/M/yyyy","de-LU":"dd.MM.yyyy","en-CA":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-GT":"dd/MM/yyyy","fr-CH":"dd.MM.yyyy","ar-DZ":"dd-MM-yyyy","zh-MO":"d/M/yyyy","de-LI":"dd.MM.yyyy","en-NZ":"d/MM/yyyy","es-CR":"dd/MM/yyyy","fr-LU":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-MA":"dd-MM-yyyy","en-IE":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-PA":"MM/dd/yyyy","fr-MC":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-TN":"dd-MM-yyyy","en-ZA":"yyyy/MM/dd","es-DO":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-OM":"dd/MM/yyyy","en-JM":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-VE":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-YE":"dd/MM/yyyy","en-029":"MM/dd/yyyy","es-CO":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-SY":"dd/MM/yyyy","en-BZ":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-PE":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-JO":"dd/MM/yyyy","en-TT":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-AR":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-LB":"dd/MM/yyyy","en-ZW":"M/d/yyyy","es-EC":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-KW":"dd/MM/yyyy","en-PH":"M/d/yyyy","es-CL":"dd-MM-yyyy","ar-AE":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-UY":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-BH":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-PY":"dd/MM/yyyy","ar-QA":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-BO":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-SV":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-HN":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-NI":"dd/MM/yyyy","es-PR":"dd/MM/yyyy","am-ET":"d/M/yyyy","tzm-Latn-DZ":"dd-MM-yyyy","iu-Latn-CA":"d/MM/yyyy","sma-NO":"dd.MM.yyyy","mn-Mong-CN":"yyyy/M/d","gd-GB":"dd/MM/yyyy","en-MY":"d/M/yyyy","prs-AF":"dd/MM/yy","bn-BD":"dd-MM-yy","wo-SN":"dd/MM/yyyy","rw-RW":"M/d/yyyy","qut-GT":"dd/MM/yyyy","sah-RU":"MM.dd.yyyy","gsw-FR":"dd/MM/yyyy","co-FR":"dd/MM/yyyy","oc-FR":"dd/MM/yyyy","mi-NZ":"dd/MM/yyyy","ga-IE":"dd/MM/yyyy","se-SE":"yyyy-MM-dd","br-FR":"dd/MM/yyyy","smn-FI":"d.M.yyyy","moh-CA":"M/d/yyyy","arn-CL":"dd-MM-yyyy","ii-CN":"yyyy/M/d","dsb-DE":"d. M. yyyy","ig-NG":"d/M/yyyy","kl-GL":"dd-MM-yyyy","lb-LU":"dd/MM/yyyy","ba-RU":"dd.MM.yy","nso-ZA":"yyyy/MM/dd","quz-BO":"dd/MM/yyyy","yo-NG":"d/M/yyyy","ha-Latn-NG":"d/M/yyyy","fil-PH":"M/d/yyyy","ps-AF":"dd/MM/yy","fy-NL":"d-M-yyyy","ne-NP":"M/d/yyyy","se-NO":"dd.MM.yyyy","iu-Cans-CA":"d/M/yyyy","sr-Latn-RS":"d.M.yyyy","si-LK":"yyyy-MM-dd","sr-Cyrl-RS":"d.M.yyyy","lo-LA":"dd/MM/yyyy","km-KH":"yyyy-MM-dd","cy-GB":"dd/MM/yyyy","bo-CN":"yyyy/M/d","sms-FI":"d.M.yyyy","as-IN":"dd-MM-yyyy","ml-IN":"dd-MM-yy","en-IN":"dd-MM-yyyy","or-IN":"dd-MM-yy","bn-IN":"dd-MM-yy","tk-TM":"dd.MM.yy","bs-Latn-BA":"d.M.yyyy","mt-MT":"dd/MM/yyyy","sr-Cyrl-ME":"d.M.yyyy","se-FI":"d.M.yyyy","zu-ZA":"yyyy/MM/dd","xh-ZA":"yyyy/MM/dd","tn-ZA":"yyyy/MM/dd","hsb-DE":"d. M. yyyy","bs-Cyrl-BA":"d.M.yyyy","tg-Cyrl-TJ":"dd.MM.yy","sr-Latn-BA":"d.M.yyyy","smj-NO":"dd.MM.yyyy","rm-CH":"dd/MM/yyyy","smj-SE":"yyyy-MM-dd","quz-EC":"dd/MM/yyyy","quz-PE":"dd/MM/yyyy","hr-BA":"d.M.yyyy.","sr-Latn-ME":"d.M.yyyy","sma-SE":"yyyy-MM-dd","en-SG":"d/M/yyyy","ug-CN":"yyyy-M-d","sr-Cyrl-BA":"d.M.yyyy","es-US":"M/d/yyyy"};

  var l = navigator.language ? navigator.language : navigator['userLanguage'],
    y = d.getFullYear(),
    m = d.getMonth() + 1,
    d = d.getDate();
  f = (l in f) ? f[l] : "MM/dd/yyyy";

  function z(s) {
    s = '' + s;
    return s.length > 1 ? s : '0' + s;
  }
  f = f.replace(/yyyy/, y);
  f = f.replace(/yy/, String(y).substr(2));
  f = f.replace(/MM/, z(m));
  f = f.replace(/M/, m);
  f = f.replace(/dd/, z(d));
  f = f.replace(/d/, d);
  return f;
}
```

Comment: This works, but unfourtunatelly it does not take care of two-letter language codes thats some browsers send (I am reffering to firefox giving me e.g. "da" instead of "da-DK"). I guess I will just add the two-letter codes for the languages I want to support, but the really cool solution would be to find and default to some Language Culture Name from the two-lettered code.

Comment: Hello @holden321 Can i get local time and convert into dd/MM/yyyy format? I asked a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36226676/how-to-convert-date-and-time-convert-into-different-2-zone but anyone not help me.

Comment: This works in the browser but not in NodeJS. NodeJS will produce the same format always with the different options above.

Answer (score 12):

```js
function getDatePattern(locale) {
  // expected style = year: 2010, month: 12, day: 31
  var options = { year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit" };

  // formatToParts() returns array of object breaking down the locales dateformat
  // [ 
  //  {type: "month", value: "03"},
  //  {type: "literal", value: "/"},
  //  {type: "day", value: "30"},
  //  {type: "literal", value: "/"},
  //  {type: "year", value: "2021"},
  // ]
  var formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, options).formatToParts();

  return formatter.map(function(e) {
      switch(e.type) {
        case 'month':
          return 'MM'; break;
        case 'day':
          return 'DD'; break;
        case 'year':
          return 'YYYY'; break;
        default: 
          return e.value;
      };
    }).join('');
}

// "YYYY/MM/DD"
console.log(getDatePattern('en'));
// "YYYY. MM. DD."
console.log(getDatePattern('ko'));
```

Comment: I don't think this is perfect because, according to the list above, there are some cultures that use "M" instead of "MM" or "d" instead of "dd".  But it seems pretty good for my purposes.

Answer (score 10):

**Can't be done.**

Cross-browser JavaScript has no way to use the actual short date format selected by the user on platforms that offer such regional customization. Besides, JavaScript has huge holes where any sort of formatting is concerned. Look how much hassle zero-padding is!

You can go to great lengths to obtain the language setting, and get the *typical* format for that locale. That's a lot of work when you don't even know if it's the correct locale (I'd bet that international language headers are often incorrect or not specific enough), or if the user has customized the format to something else.

You can try using client VBScript (which has functions for all of these regional formatting permutations), but that's not a good idea because it's a dying (dead?) IE-specific technology.

You can also try using Java/Flash/Silverlight to dig up the format. This is also a great deal of extra work, but may have the best chance for success. You'd want to cache it for the session to minimize the overhead.

Hopefully the HTML5 <time> element will provide some relief for i18n date/time display.

Comment: It's 2022 now. It can be done easily and efficiently with JS, and in many different ways.

Comment: @MissingUser If you get a value of `11/12/20`, how do you access the client's local or regional date formatting template to know which fields are year, month, and day?

Comment: This answer demonstrates how to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33969170/. As you probably were expecting, it's kind of complicated but definitely works

Comment: @MissingUser That's a useful module, but it looks like you still need to know the client locale identifier to use it, don't you?

Comment: That is a downside, but the locale is provided in many browsers. (it might not work on IE but that's dead now)

Comment: @MissingUser No it cannot. You can only get the locale but you cannot get the actual date format which can be changed by user at his OS settings. Intl.DateTimeFormat always formats date based on the given/default locale, it ignores the system's date format settings. However, <input type="date"> does honor the system format settings so as far as I can see there is no way to tell accurately, within javascript, that how an input will display a given date

Comment: @Xinchao I was talking about getting the locale not the current time. Sorry incase I confused you.

Comment: @MissingUser What I am saying is that brianary was correct, and is still correct even today (2023). Just to be clear, the OP is not asking about locale. He is asking about getting the Short Date Format as specified in the Control Panel, and it might be DIFFERENT from the format implied by the locale. So you can guess the format by checking the locale or the language, but Short Date Format is an OS level setting that can be controlled separately. Whatever you "inferred" from the locale/language is just a best effort guess. I mentioned HTML input date because that is where OS format is rendered

Answer (score 10):

If your question about [`<input type="date">`](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-date) field, here is script for getting filed `value=""` attribute:

```
(new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

You can use the [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) object ([ecma-402](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/4.0/index.html#datetimeformat-objects)) to get `data-date-pattern=""`:

```
(new Intl.DateTimeFormat()).resolved.pattern // "M/d/y" for "en-US" in Google Chrome
```

And finnaly, to format date in current l10n, `data-date=""`:

```
(new Intl.DateTimeFormat()).format(new Date());
```

Polyfill: https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/issues/129

Comment: Is the object (new Intl.DateTimeFormat()).resolved in the standards? It is not documented in MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) and does not work in Firefox.

Comment: `(new Intl.DateTimeFormat()).resolved.pattern` generates an error in Google Chrome. `(new Intl.DateTimeFormat()).resolved` is `undefined`. This is not a solution to obtaining the format string, but you can use `((new Intl.DateTimeFormat()).format(new Date());` to get a formatted date string.

Comment: For now, `(new Intl.DateTimeFormat()).resolvedOptions()` - will give you format object

Comment: @iegik `resolvedOptions` produces coarse data only (on Chrome 80 at least), eg. info about length of year's representation, order of date components, separator of date components are all missing.

Comment: @iegik You need to replace `(new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0]` with `new Date().toLocaleDateString("sv")`. Because at midnight and how ever many hours the timezone offset is the date will be wrong. I.e. 2022-01-01T00:00:00 in France is 2021-12-31T23:00:00 UTC, and toISOString returns UTC.

Answer (score 8):

Short date patterns:

```
const shortDatePatterns = {
'aa-DJ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'aa-ER': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'aa-ET': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'af': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'af-NA': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'af-ZA': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'agq-CM': "d/M/yyyy",
'ak-GH': "yyyy/MM/dd",
'am': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'am-ET': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ar': "dd/MM/yy",
'ar-001': "d/M/yyyy",
'ar-AE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ar-BH': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ar-DJ': "d/M/yyyy",
'ar-DZ': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'ar-EG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ar-ER': "d/M/yyyy",
'ar-IL': "d/M/yyyy",
'ar-IQ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ar-JO': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ar-KM': "d/M/yyyy",
'ar-KW': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ar-LB': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ar-LY': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ar-MA': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'ar-MR': "d/M/yyyy",
'ar-OM': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ar-PS': "d/M/yyyy",
'ar-QA': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ar-SA': "dd/MM/yy",
'ar-SD': "d/M/yyyy",
'ar-SO': "d/M/yyyy",
'ar-SS': "d/M/yyyy",
'ar-SY': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ar-TD': "d/M/yyyy",
'ar-TN': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'ar-YE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'arn-CL': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'as': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'as-IN': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'asa-TZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ast-ES': "d/M/yyyy",
'az': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'az-Cyrl-AZ': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'az-Latn-AZ': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'ba': "dd.MM.yy",
'ba-RU': "dd.MM.yy",
'bas-CM': "d/M/yyyy",
'be': "dd.MM.yy",
'be-BY': "dd.MM.yy",
'bem-ZM': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'bez-TZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'bg': "d.M.yyyy 'г.'",
'bg-BG': "d.M.yyyy 'г.'",
'bin-NG': "d/M/yyyy",
'bm': "d/M/yyyy",
'bm-Latn-ML': "d/M/yyyy",
'bn': "d/M/yyyy",
'bn-BD': "d/M/yyyy",
'bn-IN': "dd-MM-yy",
'bo': "yyyy/M/d",
'bo-CN': "yyyy/M/d",
'bo-IN': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'br': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'br-FR': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'brx-IN': "M/d/yyyy",
'bs': "d.M.yyyy.",
'bs-Cyrl-BA': "d.M.yyyy",
'bs-Latn-BA': "d.M.yyyy.",
'byn-ER': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ca': "d/M/yyyy",
'ca-AD': "d/M/yyyy",
'ca-ES': "d/M/yyyy",
'ca-ES-valencia': "d/M/yyyy",
'ca-FR': "d/M/yyyy",
'ca-IT': "d/M/yyyy",
'ce-RU': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'cgg-UG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'chr-Cher-US': "M/d/yyyy",
'co': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'co-FR': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'cs-CZ': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'cu': "yyyy.MM.dd",
'cu-RU': "yyyy.MM.dd",
'cy': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'cy-GB': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'da-DK': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'da-GL': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'dav-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'de': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'de-AT': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'de-BE': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'de-CH': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'de-DE': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'de-IT': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'de-LI': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'de-LU': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'dje-NE': "d/M/yyyy",
'dsb-DE': "d. M. yyyy",
'dua-CM': "d/M/yyyy",
'dv-MV': "dd/MM/yy",
'dyo-SN': "d/M/yyyy",
'dz': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'dz-BT': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'ebu-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ee': "M/d/yyyy",
'ee-GH': "M/d/yyyy",
'ee-TG': "M/d/yyyy",
'el-CY': "d/M/yyyy",
'el-GR': "d/M/yyyy",
'en-001': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-029': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-150': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-AG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-AI': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-AS': "M/d/yyyy",
'en-AT': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-AU': "d/MM/yyyy",
'en-BB': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-BE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-BI': "M/d/yyyy",
'en-BM': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-BS': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-BW': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-BZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-CA': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'en-CC': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-CH': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-CK': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-CM': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-CX': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-CY': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-DE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-DK': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-DM': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-ER': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-FI': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-FJ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-FK': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-FM': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-GB': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-GD': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-GG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-GH': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-GI': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-GM': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-GU': "M/d/yyyy",
'en-GY': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-HK': "d/M/yyyy",
'en-ID': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-IE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-IL': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-IM': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-IN': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'en-IO': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-JE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-JM': "d/M/yyyy",
'en-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-KI': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-KN': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-KY': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-LC': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-LR': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-LS': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-MG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-MH': "M/d/yyyy",
'en-MO': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-MP': "M/d/yyyy",
'en-MS': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-MT': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-MU': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-MW': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-MY': "d/M/yyyy",
'en-NA': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-NF': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-NG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-NL': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-NR': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-NU': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-NZ': "d/MM/yyyy",
'en-PG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-PH': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-PK': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-PN': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-PR': "M/d/yyyy",
'en-PW': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-RW': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-SB': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-SC': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-SD': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-SE': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'en-SG': "d/M/yyyy",
'en-SH': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-SI': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-SL': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-SS': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-SX': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-SZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-TC': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-TK': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-TO': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-TT': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-TV': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-TZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-UG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-UM': "M/d/yyyy",
'en-US': "M/d/yyyy",
'en-VC': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-VG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-VI': "M/d/yyyy",
'en-VU': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-WS': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-ZA': "yyyy/MM/dd",
'en-ZM': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'en-ZW': "d/M/yyyy",
'eo-001': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'es': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'es-419': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-AR': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-BO': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-BR': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-BZ': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-CL': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'es-CO': "d/MM/yyyy",
'es-CR': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-CU': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-DO': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-EC': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-ES': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'es-GQ': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-GT': "d/MM/yyyy",
'es-HN': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-MX': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'es-NI': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-PA': "MM/dd/yyyy",
'es-PE': "d/MM/yyyy",
'es-PH': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-PR': "MM/dd/yyyy",
'es-PY': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-SV': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-US': "M/d/yyyy",
'es-UY': "d/M/yyyy",
'es-VE': "d/M/yyyy",
'et': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'et-EE': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'eu-ES': "yyyy/M/d",
'ewo-CM': "d/M/yyyy",
'fa-IR': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ff-CM': "d/M/yyyy",
'ff-GN': "d/M/yyyy",
'ff-Latn-SN': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ff-MR': "d/M/yyyy",
'ff-NG': "d/M/yyyy",
'fi': "d.M.yyyy",
'fi-FI': "d.M.yyyy",
'fil-PH': "M/d/yyyy",
'fo': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'fo-DK': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'fo-FO': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'fr': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-029': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-BE': "dd-MM-yy",
'fr-BF': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-BI': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-BJ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-BL': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-CA': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'fr-CD': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-CF': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-CG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-CH': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'fr-CI': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-CM': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-DJ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-DZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-FR': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-GA': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-GF': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-GN': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-GP': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-GQ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-HT': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-KM': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-LU': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-MA': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-MC': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-MF': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-MG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-ML': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-MQ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-MR': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-MU': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-NC': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-NE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-PF': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-PM': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-RE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-RW': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-SC': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-SN': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-SY': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-TD': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-TG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-TN': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-VU': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-WF': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fr-YT': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fur-IT': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'fy-NL': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'ga': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ga-IE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'gd': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'gd-GB': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'gl': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'gl-ES': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'gn': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'gn-PY': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'gsw-CH': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'gsw-FR': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'gsw-LI': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'gu': "dd-MM-yy",
'gu-IN': "dd-MM-yy",
'guz-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'gv-IM': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ha-Latn-GH': "d/M/yyyy",
'ha-Latn-NE': "d/M/yyyy",
'ha-Latn-NG': "d/M/yyyy",
'haw-US': "d/M/yyyy",
'he-IL': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'hi-IN': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'hr': "d.M.yyyy.",
'hr-BA': "d. M. yyyy.",
'hr-HR': "d.M.yyyy.",
'hsb-DE': "d.M.yyyy",
'hu': "yyyy. MM. dd.",
'hu-HU': "yyyy. MM. dd.",
'hy-AM': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'ia-001': "yyyy/MM/dd",
'ia-FR': "yyyy/MM/dd",
'ibb-NG': "d/M/yyyy",
'id': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'id-ID': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ig-NG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ii-CN': "yyyy/M/d",
'is': "d.M.yyyy",
'is-IS': "d.M.yyyy",
'it': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'it-CH': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'it-IT': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'it-SM': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'it-VA': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'iu-Cans-CA': "d/M/yyyy",
'iu-Latn-CA': "d/MM/yyyy",
'ja-JP': "yyyy/MM/dd",
'jgo-CM': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'jmc-TZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'jv-Java-ID': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'jv-Latn-ID': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ka-GE': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'kab-DZ': "d/M/yyyy",
'kam-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'kde-TZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'kea-CV': "d/M/yyyy",
'khq-ML': "d/M/yyyy",
'ki': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ki-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'kk-KZ': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'kkj-CM': "dd/MM yyyy",
'kl-GL': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'kln-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'km': "dd/MM/yy",
'km-KH': "dd/MM/yy",
'kn': "dd-MM-yy",
'kn-IN': "dd-MM-yy",
'ko-KP': "yyyy. M. d.",
'ko-KR': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'kok-IN': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'kr': "d/M/yyyy",
'kr-NG': "d/M/yyyy",
'ks-Arab-IN': "M/d/yyyy",
'ks-Deva-IN': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'ksb-TZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ksf-CM': "d/M/yyyy",
'ksh-DE': "d. M. yyyy",
'ku-Arab-IQ': "yyyy/MM/dd",
'ku-Arab-IR': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'kw': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'kw-GB': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ky': "d-MMM yy",
'ky-KG': "d-MMM yy",
'la': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'la-001': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'lag-TZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'lb': "dd.MM.yy",
'lb-LU': "dd.MM.yy",
'lg-UG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'lkt-US': "M/d/yyyy",
'ln-AO': "d/M/yyyy",
'ln-CD': "d/M/yyyy",
'ln-CF': "d/M/yyyy",
'ln-CG': "d/M/yyyy",
'lo-LA': "d/M/yyyy",
'lrc-IQ': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'lrc-IR': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'lt': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'lt-LT': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'lu': "d/M/yyyy",
'lu-CD': "d/M/yyyy",
'luo-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'luy-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'lv': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'lv-LV': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'mas-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'mas-TZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'mer-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'mfe-MU': "d/M/yyyy",
'mg': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'mg-MG': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'mgh-MZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'mgo-CM': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'mi-NZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'mk': "dd.M.yyyy",
'mk-MK': "dd.M.yyyy",
'ml': "d/M/yyyy",
'ml-IN': "d/M/yyyy",
'mn': "yyyy.MM.dd",
'mn-MN': "yyyy.MM.dd",
'mn-Mong-CN': "yyyy/M/d",
'mn-Mong-MN': "yyyy/M/d",
'mni-IN': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'moh-CA': "M/d/yyyy",
'mr': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'mr-IN': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'ms': "d/MM/yyyy",
'ms-BN': "d/MM/yyyy",
'ms-MY': "d/MM/yyyy",
'ms-SG': "d/MM/yyyy",
'mt': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'mt-MT': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'mua-CM': "d/M/yyyy",
'my': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'my-MM': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'mzn-IR': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'naq-NA': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'nb-NO': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'nb-SJ': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'nd-ZW': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'nds-DE': "d.MM.yyyy",
'nds-NL': "d.MM.yyyy",
'ne': "M/d/yyyy",
'ne-IN': "yyyy/M/d",
'ne-NP': "M/d/yyyy",
'nl': "d-M-yyyy",
'nl-AW': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'nl-BE': "d/MM/yyyy",
'nl-BQ': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'nl-CW': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'nl-NL': "d-M-yyyy",
'nl-SR': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'nl-SX': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'nmg-CM': "d/M/yyyy",
'nn-NO': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'nnh-CM': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'no': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'nqo-GN': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'nr': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'nr-ZA': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'nso-ZA': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'nus-SS': "d/MM/yyyy",
'nyn-UG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'oc-FR': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'om': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'om-ET': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'om-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'or-IN': "dd-MM-yy",
'os-GE': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'os-RU': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'pa': "dd-MM-yy",
'pa-Arab-PK': "dd-MM-yy",
'pa-IN': "dd-MM-yy",
'pap-029': "d-M-yyyy",
'pl': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'pl-PL': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'prg-001': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'prs-AF': "yyyy/M/d",
'ps': "yyyy/M/d",
'ps-AF': "yyyy/M/d",
'pt': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'pt-AO': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'pt-BR': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'pt-CH': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'pt-CV': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'pt-GQ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'pt-GW': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'pt-LU': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'pt-MO': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'pt-MZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'pt-PT': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'pt-ST': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'pt-TL': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'quc-Latn-GT': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'quz-BO': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'quz-EC': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'quz-PE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'rm-CH': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'rn-BI': "d/M/yyyy",
'ro': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'ro-MD': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'ro-RO': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'rof-TZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ru': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'ru-BY': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'ru-KG': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'ru-KZ': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'ru-MD': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'ru-RU': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'ru-UA': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'rw': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'rw-RW': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'rwk-TZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'sa': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'sa-IN': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'sah-RU': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'saq-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'sbp-TZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'sd': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'sd-Arab-PK': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'sd-Deva-IN': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'se': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'se-FI': "d.M.yyyy",
'se-NO': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'se-SE': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'seh-MZ': "d/M/yyyy",
'ses-ML': "d/M/yyyy",
'sg': "d/M/yyyy",
'sg-CF': "d/M/yyyy",
'shi-Latn-MA': "d/M/yyyy",
'shi-Tfng-MA': "d/M/yyyy",
'si': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'si-LK': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'sk': "d. M. yyyy",
'sk-SK': "d. M. yyyy",
'sl': "d. MM. yyyy",
'sl-SI': "d. MM. yyyy",
'sma-NO': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'sma-SE': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'smj-NO': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'smj-SE': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'smn-FI': "d.M.yyyy",
'sms-FI': "d.M.yyyy",
'sn': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'sn-Latn-ZW': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'so': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'so-DJ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'so-ET': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'so-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'so-SO': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'sq-AL': "d.M.yyyy",
'sq-MK': "d.M.yyyy",
'sq-XK': "d.M.yyyy",
'sr': "d.M.yyyy.",
'sr-Cyrl-BA': "d.M.yyyy.",
'sr-Cyrl-ME': "d.M.yyyy.",
'sr-Cyrl-RS': "dd.MM.yyyy.",
'sr-Cyrl-XK': "d.M.yyyy.",
'sr-Latn-BA': "d.M.yyyy.",
'sr-Latn-ME': "d.M.yyyy.",
'sr-Latn-RS': "d.M.yyyy.",
'sr-Latn-XK': "d.M.yyyy.",
'ss': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'ss-SZ': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'ss-ZA': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'ssy-ER': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'st': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'st-LS': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'st-ZA': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'sv': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'sv-AX': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'sv-FI': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'sv-SE': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'sw-CD': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'sw-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'sw-TZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'sw-UG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'syr-SY': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ta-IN': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'ta-LK': "d/M/yyyy",
'ta-MY': "d/M/yyyy",
'ta-SG': "d/M/yyyy",
'te-IN': "dd-MM-yy",
'teo-KE': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'teo-UG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'tg': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'tg-Cyrl-TJ': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'th': "d/M/yyyy",
'th-TH': "d/M/yyyy",
'ti-ER': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'ti-ET': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'tig-ER': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'tk': "dd.MM.yy 'ý.'",
'tk-TM': "dd.MM.yy 'ý.'",
'tn': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'tn-BW': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'tn-ZA': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'to': "d/M/yyyy",
'to-TO': "d/M/yyyy",
'tr': "d.MM.yyyy",
'tr-CY': "d.MM.yyyy",
'tr-TR': "d.MM.yyyy",
'ts-ZA': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'tt': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'tt-RU': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'twq-NE': "d/M/yyyy",
'tzm-Arab-MA': "d/M/yyyy",
'tzm-Latn-DZ': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'tzm-Latn-MA': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'tzm-Tfng-MA': "dd-MM-yyyy",
'ug': "yyyy-M-d",
'ug-CN': "yyyy-M-d",
'uk-UA': "dd.MM.yyyy",
'ur-IN': "d/M/yy",
'ur-PK': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'uz': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'uz-Arab-AF': "dd/MM yyyy",
'uz-Cyrl-UZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'uz-Latn-UZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'vai-Latn-LR': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'vai-Vaii-LR': "dd/MM/yyyy",
've': "yyyy-MM-dd",
've-ZA': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'vi': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'vi-VN': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'vo-001': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'vun-TZ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'wae-CH': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'wal-ET': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'wo-SN': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'xh-ZA': "yyyy-MM-dd",
'xog-UG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'yav-CM': "d/M/yyyy",
'yi-001': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'yo-BJ': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'yo-NG': "dd/MM/yyyy",
'zgh-Tfng-MA': "d/M/yyyy",
'zh-CN': "yyyy/M/d",
'zh-Hans-HK': "d/M/yyyy",
'zh-Hans-MO': "d/M/yyyy",
'zh-HK': "d/M/yyyy",
'zh-MO': "d/M/yyyy",
'zh-SG': "d/M/yyyy",
'zh-TW': "yyyy/M/d",
'zu-ZA': "M/d/yyyy",
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of a way to do that (you can [get the language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference) and try to deduct the locale from that).

I tried to cook a little something to try and do that (only tested on Firefox with one locale). should work as long as the short date string includes the date as digits, so it might fail for, say, arabic. It might have other bugs too, i don't know all the different locales peculiarities, this is just a concept...

```
function getShortDateFormat() {
    var d = new Date(1992, 0, 7);
    var s = d.toLocaleDateString();

    function formatReplacer(str) {
        var num = parseInt(str);
        switch (num % 100) {
            case 92:
                return str.replace(/.{1}/g, "Y");
            case 1:
                return str.length == 1 ? "mM" : "MM"
            case 7:
                return str.length == 1 ? "dD" : "DD"
        }
    }

    shortDateFormat = s.replace(/\d+/g, formatReplacer);
    return shortDateFormat;
}

getShortDateFormat();
```

The outputted format will be:

- Y: the number of digits to represent years
- dD = short day (i.e. use only one digit when possible)
- DD = long day format (i.e. two digits always)
- mM/MM - same for months

So in my browser, the shortDateformat you get is "MM/DD/YYYY".

Comment: I get: "martes, DD de enero de YYYY"

Comment: Then obviously i need some more work on it :) (tested only on Firefox 3.5/Linux)

Comment: returning undefined in date part on chrome 38 X11

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the browser's `toLocaleDateString()` implementation.
For example in chrome you will get something like: `Tuesday, January DD, YYYY`

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can use this one:

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString();
```

Which can accept parameters for the locale:

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-us");
new Date().toLocaleDateString("he-il");
```

I see it is supported by chrome, IE, edge, although results may vary it does a pretty good job for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
new Date(YOUR_DATE_STRING).toLocaleDateString(navigator.language)
```

*~ combination of answers of above*

Answer (score 3):

One liner using **Intl**:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, { dateStyle: 'short', timeStyle: 'short' }).format(date)
```

*date* is the date you want to convert. *undefined* tells Intl to use the browser locale (you could also pass a locale string here).

More information on the DateTimeFormat function can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat).

Intl is supported by [many browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=Intl) already. If you need to support old browsers, you could use a polyfill ([CDN](https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl) or [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=Intl)).

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way. If you want a reliable, cross-browser solution, you'd have to build a lookup table of date, and time format strings, by culture. To format a date, parse the corresponding format string, extract the relevant parts from the date, i.e. day, month, year, and append them together.

This is essentially what Microsoft does with their AJAX library, as shown in @no's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Slight modification to Mitali's response. To dynamically generate the language for a more localized solution.

```
var lang= window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;

var date = new Date();

var options = {
   weekday: "short",
   year: "numeric",
   month: "2-digit",
   day: "numeric"
};

date.toLocaleDateString(lang, options);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using en-CA as an example, if you're using `date-fns`:

```html
<script type="module">
  import { enCA } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/date-fns/locale';
  console.log(enCA.formatLong.date({width:'short'}))
  // yyyy-MM-dd
</script>
```

Source: https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/src/locale/en-CA/_lib/formatLong/index.js

For CLDR & Paul Irish:

```
import locale from 'cldr-dates-modern/main/en-CA/ca-gregorian.json'
console.log(locale.main['en-CA'].dates.calendars.gregorian.dateFormats.short)
// y-MM-dd
```

Source: https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-dates-modern/blob/master/main/en-CA/ca-gregorian.json

Use case: we used this value as the placeholder attribute for an input.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem in JavaScript implementations.

[ECMA says `Date#toLocaleDateString()` is implementation-defined](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.tolocaledatestring).
So JavaScript implementations are free to implement host-specific date-specific locales.

The problem is that most JavaScript implementations pass on the job of printing dates to the ICU library which itself does not normally support host-specific locale definitions, [even though it is desired](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/ICU-111).

There is a "`@compat=host`" option for locales that ICU supports, but it's rarely, if ever, used and most JavaScript implementations seem to prevent setting such options on a selected locale.

Answer (score 1):

Found this thread while looking for a way to generate localized but short dates in all browsers without any extra library, just a simple call to format server generated ISO dates.

I went with a combination of holden321 and mwrf's answers. Storing the formats external to the function because it's handier that way and storing the current locale format because it's always useful.

The function can be passed anything that can be passed to a date constructor to get a valid date, and also a language or format for flexibility.

You need to set up the list of formats and a couple more things first:

```
var LOCALE_DATE_FORMATS = {
  // as per mwrf's list
  ...
}

var LANG = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;

var LOCALE_DATE_FORMAT = LOCALE_DATE_FORMATS[LANG] || 'dd/MM/yyyy';
```

Then the function is:

```
function getLocalizedDate(o, options)
{
    var res = '';
    var date = new Date(o);     

    if(o != null && !isNaN(date) && typeof(date.getFullYear) == 'function')
    {
        var d = date.getDate();
        var dd = d < 10 ? '0' + d : d;
        var M = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var MM = M < 10 ? '0' + M : M;
        var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
        var yy = new String(yyyy).substring(2);

        var format = LOCALE_DATE_FORMAT;

        if(options && options.lang)
            format = LOCALE_DATE_FORMATS[options.lang];
        else if(options && options.format)
            format = options.format;

        res = format
            .replace(/dd/g, dd)
            .replace(/d/g, d)
            .replace(/MM/g, MM)
            .replace(/M/g, M)
            .replace(/yyyy/g, yyyy)
            .replace(/yy/g, yy);
    }

    return res;
}
```

`getLocalizedDate('2013-03-01T00:00:00',  {lang:'sk-SK'})` = `1. 3. 2013`

EDIT: Call with no arguments to use the user's locale, of course:

`getLocalizedDate('2013-03-01T00:00:00')` = `01/03/2013` (for me)

If you are a fan of extending prototypes, the first lines of the function definition become:

```
Date.prototype.getLocalized = function(options)
{
  var date = this;
```

Called of course like this:

`new Date('2013-03-01T00:00:00').getLocalized({lang:'sk-SK'})` = `1. 3. 2013`

EDIT: Again, call with no arguments to use the user's locale:

`new Date('2013-03-01T00:00:00').getLocalized()` = `01/03/2013` (for me)

Answer (score 1):

const newDate = new Date();
const currentDate = newDate.toLocaleDateString("sv-SE",{year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' });

Comment: Can you add more context and format your code?

Comment: can you apply formmatting and add addidtional details?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```js
// pass in a localeAbbv string to get the format for a specific locale,
// otherwise the browser's default localte will be used
function getLocaleShortDateFormat(localeAbbv?: string) {
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(Intl.DateTimeFormat(localeAbbv).resolvedOptions().locale)
        .format(new Date(2021, 0, 2))
        .replace(/0?1/, "MM").replace(/0?2/, "DD").replace(/(?:20)?21/, "YYYY");
}
```

This is just taking a known date (2 Jan 2021), formatting it using the current locale, and then replacing the known values (2021=year, 1=month, 2=day) with the appropriate date strings.

This uses standards-compliant method calls and I think should work in all modern(ish) browsers.

Actually I think it's better to use "-" instead of "/" for separating the components of the date when formatting dates for displaying to users.  Couple of reasons for this: 1) it provides better UX in that it's easier to discern the components because "-" is not as tall as the numbers so the breaks between the date components stand out better, and 2) it's closer to the ISO 8601 format, which uses dashes between the date components.  To do this, just add another `.replace(/\//g, "-")` to the chain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a date from the form  .you have to use this.

```js
const date_ = new Date(props.date);
const month = date_.toLocaleString("en", { month: "long" });
const day = date_.toLocaleString("en-029", { day: "2-digit" });
const year = date_.toLocaleString("en-US", { year: "numeric" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the browser handle the positioning. Use unique numbers in the date to be able to identify them and replace them with the format of your choice (in my case DD, MM and YYYY) and change the separator if necessary:

```
const getLocaleDateFormat = (separator: string = '-') => {
  // A fake date and with each part different to be able to identify later
  const fakeDate = new Date();
  fakeDate.setDate(22);
  fakeDate.setMonth(10); // index
  fakeDate.setFullYear(1999);

  const format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language)
    .format(fakeDate)
    .replace(fakeDate.getDate().toString(), 'DD')
    // also consider the month as an index
    .replace((fakeDate.getMonth() + 1).toString(), 'MM')
    .replace(fakeDate.getFullYear().toString(), 'YYYY');

  return format.replace(/\W/g, separator);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

For an output such as MO/DY/YEAR or DY/MO/YEAR (or whichever format is pertinent to your locale)

```
let time = new Date()
let timestampDate = new Date(time).toLocaleDateString(navigator.language)
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
new Date().toLocaleFormat("%x");
```

All formats for this function can be found here:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html

Comment: using this method caused me so much pain I had to throw it out.  Chrome won't recognize it.

Comment: I have to agree with previous commenters: Stay away from this function if you can.

Comment: Did you mean [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)?? Because this isn't even documentated on mdn!

Answer (score -3):

**(2021)**

Just use `.toLocaleDateString()`, the browser will handle everything for you, e.g.:

```js
console.log(
  new Date().toLocaleDateString()
); // -> something like '7/18/2021', depending on user's location
```

To verify it works for anybody, pass in a locale string to test:

```js
const toVerify = [
  'af-ZA',
  'am-ET',
  'ar-AE',
  'ar-BH',
  'ar-DZ',
  'ar-EG',
  'ar-IQ',
  'ar-JO',
  'ar-KW',
  'ar-LB',
  'ar-LY',
  'ar-MA',
  'ar-OM',
  'ar-QA',
  'ar-SA',
  'ar-SY',
  'ar-TN',
  'ar-YE',
  'arn-CL',
  'as-IN',
  'az-Cyrl-AZ',
  'az-Latn-AZ',
  'ba-RU',
  'be-BY',
  'bg-BG',
  'bn-BD',
  'bn-IN',
  'bo-CN',
  'br-FR',
  'bs-Cyrl-BA',
  'bs-Latn-BA',
  'ca-ES',
  'co-FR',
  'cs-CZ',
  'cy-GB',
  'da-DK',
  'de-AT',
  'de-CH',
  'de-DE',
  'de-LI',
  'de-LU',
  'dsb-DE',
  'dv-MV',
  'el-GR',
  'en-029',
  'en-AU',
  'en-BZ',
  'en-CA',
  'en-GB',
  'en-IE',
  'en-IN',
  'en-JM',
  'en-MY',
  'en-NZ',
  'en-PH',
  'en-SG',
  'en-TT',
  'en-US',
  'en-ZA',
  'en-ZW',
  'es-AR',
  'es-BO',
  'es-CL',
  'es-CO',
  'es-CR',
  'es-DO',
  'es-EC',
  'es-ES',
  'es-GT',
  'es-HN',
  'es-MX',
  'es-NI',
  'es-PA',
  'es-PE',
  'es-PR',
  'es-PY',
  'es-SV',
  'es-US',
  'es-UY',
  'es-VE',
  'et-EE',
  'eu-ES',
  'fa-IR',
  'fi-FI',
  'fil-PH',
  'fo-FO',
  'fr-BE',
  'fr-CA',
  'fr-CH',
  'fr-FR',
  'fr-LU',
  'fr-MC',
  'fy-NL',
  'ga-IE',
  'gd-GB',
  'gl-ES',
  'gsw-FR',
  'gu-IN',
  'ha-Latn-NG',
  'he-IL',
  'hi-IN',
  'hr-BA',
  'hr-HR',
  'hsb-DE',
  'hu-HU',
  'hy-AM',
  'id-ID',
  'ig-NG',
  'ii-CN',
  'is-IS',
  'it-CH',
  'it-IT',
  'iu-Cans-CA',
  'iu-Latn-CA',
  'ja-JP',
  'ka-GE',
  'kk-KZ',
  'kl-GL',
  'km-KH',
  'kn-IN',
  'ko-KR',
  'kok-IN',
  'ky-KG',
  'lb-LU',
  'lo-LA',
  'lt-LT',
  'lv-LV',
  'mi-NZ',
  'mk-MK',
  'ml-IN',
  'mn-MN',
  'mn-Mong-CN',
  'moh-CA',
  'mr-IN',
  'ms-BN',
  'ms-MY',
  'mt-MT',
  'nb-NO',
  'ne-NP',
  'nl-BE',
  'nl-NL',
  'nn-NO',
  'nso-ZA',
  'oc-FR',
  'or-IN',
  'pa-IN',
  'pl-PL',
  'prs-AF',
  'ps-AF',
  'pt-BR',
  'pt-PT',
  'qut-GT',
  'quz-BO',
  'quz-EC',
  'quz-PE',
  'rm-CH',
  'ro-RO',
  'ru-RU',
  'rw-RW',
  'sa-IN',
  'sah-RU',
  'se-FI',
  'se-NO',
  'se-SE',
  'si-LK',
  'sk-SK',
  'sl-SI',
  'sma-NO',
  'sma-SE',
  'smj-NO',
  'smj-SE',
  'smn-FI',
  'sms-FI',
  'sq-AL',
  'sr-Cyrl-BA',
  'sr-Cyrl-CS',
  'sr-Cyrl-ME',
  'sr-Cyrl-RS',
  'sr-Latn-BA',
  'sr-Latn-CS',
  'sr-Latn-ME',
  'sr-Latn-RS',
  'sv-FI',
  'sv-SE',
  'sw-KE',
  'syr-SY',
  'ta-IN',
  'te-IN',
  'tg-Cyrl-TJ',
  'th-TH',
  'tk-TM',
  'tn-ZA',
  'tr-TR',
  'tt-RU',
  'tzm-Latn-DZ',
  'ug-CN',
  'uk-UA',
  'ur-PK',
  'uz-Cyrl-UZ',
  'uz-Latn-UZ',
  'vi-VN',
  'wo-SN',
  'xh-ZA',
  'yo-NG',
  'zh-CN',
  'zh-HK',
  'zh-MO',
  'zh-SG',
  'zh-TW',
  'zu-ZA',
];

toVerify.forEach((locale) => {
  console.log(locale, new Date().toLocaleDateString(locale));
});
```

Answer (score -5):

Try to use Date.CultureInfo.formatPatterns.shortDate

Comment: The question asks for javascript, not C#.