# C# DateTimeKind.Local in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript

I just want to know that what is equivalent of C# DateTimeKind.Local in JavaScript and how can I set it in JavaScript

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388115/get-locale-short-date-format-using-javascript ??

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support for most of DateTime localization methods in JavaScript. Also in your case simple `new Date()` returns date in browser's local time zone if it is enough for you.

If you have JQuery consider using https://github.com/jquery/globalize to deal with number/date formatting.

Comment: Hi I am not using JavaScript in a browser I am using in Titanium for mobile application development.

Comment: Don't know than. Sorry - could not sense it in the question.