# How do I format a Date object with users preference instead of locale?

Tags: javascript, date

EDIT: I think it's crazy that JavaScript can talk to USB devices but can't simply pull the OS' preferred date format. Doing more research, this question is a duplicate of [Javascript - Retrieve OS Date formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834855/javascript-retrieve-os-date-formatting). Thanks to everybody who tried to help anyway.

How do you format a date to the user's system preferred format? Previous research I have done indicates that `getLocaleDateString()` will do this, however, I am still seeing incorrect behavior.

Browser's locale is set to "en_US". OS' date format is is set to 2020-03-11. When I call `(new Date()).getLocaleDateString()`, I get 3/11/2020, which is not the format I'd expect. I cannot seem to find any JavaScript methods that will format to a user's preferred date format, nor can I find any settings in my browser to alter this format either. I feel like I must be doing something wrong because it seems weird that application developers would responsible for date formatting for the user.

Comment: with your choice of numbers its not clear what is the month/day... could you update with 31/12/2020 as your example date

Comment: you can use `moment.js` to format dates or you can do it all yourself manually

Comment: As usual with dates manipulations, [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) will save you a few headaches.

Comment: See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: Please, for the love of everything good, get [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Using moment.js does not answer this question, nor does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer (at least today) seems to be that this is not possible. I have found this duplicate question that has no answers on it: [Javascript - Retrieve OS Date formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834855/javascript-retrieve-os-date-formatting).

If anybody knows the actual answer to this question, answer this other question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameters to the `.toLocalString()` method.

```
en-us format: MM/dd/yy h:mm a
new Date().toLocaleString('en-us', { timeZone: 'UTC' })
returns "3/11/2020, 3:02:21 PM"
```

```
en-gb format: DD/MM/YYY HH:MM
new Date().toLocaleString('en-gb', { timeZone: 'UTC' })
returns "11/03/2020, 15:02:26"
```

BTW: `.toLocalString()` looks at the browsers settings, not the OS's.

Comment: The question clearly states independent of language/region.

Comment: For the date format browser settings you are looking for, it is the language of the browser/preffered website language that is determinating the date format.

Answer (score -1):

If you prefer not using `momentjs` and do it yourself,You can extract individual values like this and format into any format you want

```
const dateValue = new Date(dateString);
const dd = dateValue.getDate();
const MM = dateValue.getMonth() + 1;
const yyyy = dateValue.getFullYear();
```

For example to convert `today's date` to `mm/dd/yyyy` format

```js
const date=new Date();
console.log(date);

const formatDate=(dateString,requiredFormat)=>{
const dd=dateString.getDate();
const mm=dateString.getMonth()+1;
const yyyy=dateString.getFullYear();
 if(requiredFormat.toLowerCase()==='mm/dd/yyyy')
   return `${mm}/${dd}/${yyyy}`
}

console.log(formatDate(date,'mm/dd/yyyy'));
```

Comment: The question clearly states that I do not want to specify a format.

Comment: what is the `format` that you are expecting

Comment: Read the question. I want to format the date in the user's preferred date format.

Comment: @Ryan, this user's preferred date format, what is this? a variable, right? Then you replace `'mm/dd/yyyy'` with this variable.