# List of JavaSscript Date toLocaleDateString datetime formats

Tags: javascript, internationalization, locale, date-formatting

Where can the official list of [Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) formats be found? It's not linked from that MDN page, and the accepted answer to [this confusingly phrased question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388115/get-locale-short-date-format-using-javascript) lists a different set of formats. The [CLDR database](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-dates-modern/tree/master/main) is hard to consume.

What I want is a simple map, like the one below:

```js
const date = new Date();
for (const locale of ['en-US', 'en-GB', 'en-CA'])
  console.log(locale, '=>', date.toLocaleDateString(locale, {  }));
```

Bonus points for passing `{ month: 'short' }` instead of an empty options object.

Comment: What do you mean by "official"? The output of [*toLocaleString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date.prototype.tolocalestring) is either based on [*ECMA-402*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/5.0/index.html#sec-partitiondatetimepattern) or whatever the implementation decides is appropriate. Even where ECMA-402 is supported, the format may differ between implementations. The sequence of values may also change depending on the options, e.g. it might be common in Britain to use "September 23, 2018" but the shortened version would be written "23/9/2018".

Comment: @RobG: I'm looking for a map from [all the locale codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549577/javascript-get-the-complete-list-of-locales-supported-by-the-browser) to the particular format output by `date.toLocaleDateString(locale, {  })`, but decoded as `YYYY${sep}MM${sep}DD`, in whatever order these appear.

Comment: I think that what you were looking for was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9893752/17089665)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Locale Short Date Format using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388115/get-locale-short-date-format-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the List I found, not exhaustive though.

1. https://html-shark.com/HTML/LanguageCodes.htm (Covers a lot)
2. http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm (backup)

EDITED:
a more comprehensive list
https://gist.github.com/mlconnor/1887156