# JavaScript - get the complete list of locales supported by the browser

Tags: javascript, localization, ecmascript-next

I've found [supportedLocalesOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/supportedLocalesOf), but is there a way to get *all* supported locales, not just check which among a given list are supported?

The '*' tag option described in [this 2012 post](https://marcoscaceres.github.io/jsi18n/) no longer works.

Comment: Hello Dan, I read your blog on *English as a global language* and it rang a bell in my own experience as a third language learner turned quasi-fluent and a constant advocate of *English is the only skill you learn at school that will last a lifetime*. I noticed that both dandascalescu.com and dandv.me are inaccessible. Do you intend to reduce your Internet exposure?

Answer (score 7):

You may use [npm ISO-639-1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso-639-1) to list them. It's safe to assume that all browsers use the `639-1` column shown in [this table from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) as their standard support.

Or use the following hardcoded list

```
[
    ['Abkhazian', 'ab'],
    ['Afar', 'aa'],
    ['Afrikaans', 'af'],
    ['Akan', 'ak'],
    ['Albanian', 'sq'],
    ['Amharic', 'am'],
    ['Arabic', 'ar'],
    ['Aragonese', 'an'],
    ['Argentina', 'es-ar'],
    ['Armenian', 'hy'],
    ['Assamese', 'as'],
    ['Avaric', 'av'],
    ['Avestan', 'ae'],
    ['Aymara', 'ay'],
    ['Azerbaijani', 'az'],
    ['Bambara', 'bm'],
    ['Bashkir', 'ba'],
    ['Basque', 'eu'],
    ['Belarusian', 'be'],
    ['Bengali (Bangla)', 'bn'],
    ['Bihari', 'bh'],
    ['Bislama', 'bi'],
    ['Bosnian', 'bs'],
    ['Breton', 'br'],
    ['Bulgarian', 'bg'],
    ['Burmese', 'my'],
    ['Catalan', 'ca'],
    ['Chamorro', 'ch'],
    ['Chechen', 'ce'],
    ['Chichewa, Chewa, Nyanja', 'ny'],
    ['Chinese', 'zh'],
    ['Chinese (Simplified)', 'zh-Hans'],
    ['Chinese (Traditional)', 'zh-Hant'],
    ['Chuvash', 'cv'],
    ['Cornish', 'kw'],
    ['Corsican', 'co'],
    ['Cree', 'cr'],
    ['Croatian', 'hr'],
    ['Czech', 'cs'],
    ['Danish', 'da'],
    ['Divehi, Dhivehi, Maldivian', 'dv'],
    ['Dutch', 'nl'],
    ['Dzongkha', 'dz'],
    ['English', 'en'],
    ['Esperanto', 'eo'],
    ['Estonian', 'et'],
    ['Ewe', 'ee'],
    ['Faroese', 'fo'],
    ['Fijian', 'fj'],
    ['Finnish', 'fi'],
    ['French', 'fr'],
    ['Fula, Fulah, Pulaar, Pular', 'ff'],
    ['Galician', 'gl'],
    ['Gaelic (Scottish)', 'gd'],
    ['Gaelic (Manx)', 'gv'],
    ['Georgian', 'ka'],
    ['German', 'de'],
    ['Greek', 'el'],
    ['Greenlandic', 'kl'],
    ['Guarani', 'gn'],
    ['Gujarati', 'gu'],
    ['Haitian Creole', 'ht'],
    ['Hausa', 'ha'],
    ['Hebrew', 'he'],
    ['Herero', 'hz'],
    ['Hindi', 'hi'],
    ['Hiri Motu', 'ho'],
    ['Hungarian', 'hu'],
    ['Icelandic', 'is'],
    ['Ido', 'io'],
    ['Igbo', 'ig'],
    ['Indonesian', 'id, in'],
    ['Interlingua', 'ia'],
    ['Interlingue', 'ie'],
    ['Inuktitut', 'iu'],
    ['Inupiak', 'ik'],
    ['Irish', 'ga'],
    ['Italian', 'it'],
    ['Japanese', 'ja'],
    ['Javanese', 'jv'],
    ['Kalaallisut, Greenlandic', 'kl'],
    ['Kannada', 'kn'],
    ['Kanuri', 'kr'],
    ['Kashmiri', 'ks'],
    ['Kazakh', 'kk'],
    ['Khmer', 'km'],
    ['Kikuyu', 'ki'],
    ['Kinyarwanda (Rwanda)', 'rw'],
    ['Kirundi', 'rn'],
    ['Kyrgyz', 'ky'],
    ['Komi', 'kv'],
    ['Kongo', 'kg'],
    ['Korean', 'ko'],
    ['Kurdish', 'ku'],
    ['Kwanyama', 'kj'],
    ['Lao', 'lo'],
    ['Latin', 'la'],
    ['Latvian (Lettish)', 'lv'],
    ['Limburgish ( Limburger)', 'li'],
    ['Lingala', 'ln'],
    ['Lithuanian', 'lt'],
    ['Luga-Katanga', 'lu'],
    ['Luganda, Ganda', 'lg'],
    ['Luxembourgish', 'lb'],
    ['Manx', 'gv'],
    ['Macedonian', 'mk'],
    ['Malagasy', 'mg'],
    ['Malay', 'ms'],
    ['Malayalam', 'ml'],
    ['Maltese', 'mt'],
    ['Maori', 'mi'],
    ['Marathi', 'mr'],
    ['Marshallese', 'mh'],
    ['Moldavian', 'mo'],
    ['Mongolian', 'mn'],
    ['Nauru', 'na'],
    ['Navajo', 'nv'],
    ['Ndonga', 'ng'],
    ['Northern Ndebele', 'nd'],
    ['Nepali', 'ne'],
    ['Norwegian', 'no'],
    ['Norwegian bokmål', 'nb'],
    ['Norwegian nynorsk', 'nn'],
    ['Nuosu', 'ii'],
    ['Occitan', 'oc'],
    ['Ojibwe', 'oj'],
    ['Old Church Slavonic, Old Bulgarian', 'cu'],
    ['Oriya', 'or'],
    ['Oromo (Afaan Oromo)', 'om'],
    ['Ossetian', 'os'],
    ['Pāli', 'pi'],
    ['Pashto, Pushto', 'ps'],
    ['Persian (Farsi)', 'fa'],
    ['Polish', 'pl'],
    ['Portuguese', 'pt'],
    ['Punjabi (Eastern)', 'pa'],
    ['Quechua', 'qu'],
    ['Romansh', 'rm'],
    ['Romanian', 'ro'],
    ['Russian', 'ru'],
    ['Sami', 'se'],
    ['Samoan', 'sm'],
    ['Sango', 'sg'],
    ['Sanskrit', 'sa'],
    ['Serbian', 'sr'],
    ['Serbo-Croatian', 'sh'],
    ['Sesotho', 'st'],
    ['Setswana', 'tn'],
    ['Shona', 'sn'],
    ['Sichuan Yi', 'ii'],
    ['Sindhi', 'sd'],
    ['Sinhalese', 'si'],
    ['Siswati', 'ss'],
    ['Slovak', 'sk'],
    ['Slovenian', 'sl'],
    ['Somali', 'so'],
    ['Southern Ndebele', 'nr'],
    ['Spanish', 'es'],
    ['Sundanese', 'su'],
    ['Swahili (Kiswahili)', 'sw'],
    ['Swati', 'ss'],
    ['Swedish', 'sv'],
    ['Tagalog', 'tl'],
    ['Tahitian', 'ty'],
    ['Tajik', 'tg'],
    ['Tamil', 'ta'],
    ['Tatar', 'tt'],
    ['Telugu', 'te'],
    ['Thai', 'th'],
    ['Tibetan', 'bo'],
    ['Tigrinya', 'ti'],
    ['Tonga', 'to'],
    ['Tsonga', 'ts'],
    ['Turkish', 'tr'],
    ['Turkmen', 'tk'],
    ['Twi', 'tw'],
    ['Uyghur', 'ug'],
    ['Ukrainian', 'uk'],
    ['Urdu', 'ur'],
    ['Uzbek', 'uz'],
    ['Venda', 've'],
    ['Vietnamese', 'vi'],
    ['Volapük', 'vo'],
    ['Wallon', 'wa'],
    ['Welsh', 'cy'],
    ['Wolof', 'wo'],
    ['Western Frisian', 'fy'],
    ['Xhosa', 'xh'],
    ['Yiddish', 'yi', 'ji'],
    ['Yoruba', 'yo'],
    ['Zhuang, Chuang', 'za'],
    ['Zulu', 'zu'],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The locale used and the form of the string returned are entirely implementation-dependen. It uses a string with a BCP 47 language tag. It is somehow still related to unicode locale.

You still can find the list of locales argument in *Country Code* list. But if some of the country code does not work, you can go [UNICODE LOCALE DATA MARKUP LANGUAGE (LDML)](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35.html#BCP_47_Conformance) to see the list of correct locales implemented there.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Locale_identification_and_negotiation

Answer (score -2):

I looked at this a little bit, and did some testing use Chrome.

```
navigator.languages
```

This returns an array of supported languages. Initially mine was only en-Us and en, however I added Welsh, and it was returned.

Comment: It only return the current language the browser use

Comment: It's not the list of supported languages, it's the list of languages which the client said they want. The first one is most specific, the later ones are fallbacks.