# InputMask js display backend date

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I am using InputMask js (version 4.x) for date/datetime formatting.

I am trying to format a backend date which comes like this: 
2018-03-23T00:00:00.000+01:00
and want to display it like this: yyyy.mm.dd

I tried to set the inputFormat attribute to 'yyyy.mm.dd' but it's not working. Instead, seems to work with mm.dd.yyyy, but I would like to display that backend date in different formats.

Here is the code:

```
(function($){


  $('input').val(new Date('2018-03-23T00:00:00.000+01:00').toLocaleDateString());

  $('input').inputmask("datetime",{
    inputFormat: 'yyyy.mm.dd'
  });


})(jQuery)
```

And a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zq46eg90/8/

I would expect here to have '2018.03.23' displayed, but the actual result is something else (3232.01.08)

Comment: did you try my answer? is there any issue?

Comment: Yes, tried it. Seems to work but I don't want right now to add another library to the project. I will go for now with this solution: 
$('input').val(new Date('2018-03-23T00:00:00.000+01:00').toLocaleDateString('lt-LT'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `lt-LT` locale. [(more locales)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9893752/8053274)

```
$('input').val(new Date('2018-03-23T00:00:00.000+01:00').toLocaleDateString('lt-LT'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use momentjs for your case.

```
(function($){

  var date = moment(new Date('2018-03-23T00:00:00.000+01:00').toLocaleDateString());
  $('input').val(date.format('YYYY.MM.DD'));

  $('input').inputmask("datetime",{
    inputFormat: 'yyyy.mm.dd'
  });


})(jQuery)
```

See demo
https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/qLgsob41/3/