# Elixir: Local System Date Format

Tags: date, elixir, locale

Is it possible to find out the date format the machine is using in Elixir? i.e. dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy so we can format a date string accordingly?

Comment: Machines do not use any specific “date format,” you might want to ask internets about `LC_TIME` environment variable though.

Comment: In Javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388115/get-locale-short-date-format-using-javascript#answer-9893752  - all you need is the environment var of `LC_TIME`  using `System.get_env(varname)` and then adapt the that Js array.

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff I looked at using LC_TIME. If I execute locale it gives me LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8" which is right. I can look this up to get the dd-mm-yyyy format in the javascript arrays.  If I change my date format to mm-dd-yy on the computer then LC_TIME does not change, so it's close but it is still not really the date format.

Comment: @iphaaw when you change your date format what way do you do it? Is it on windows, mac, linux?

Comment: I was changing it on Mac through the system preferences. We primarily need it to be on Windows but Mac and Linux will be useful too. Thanks.

Comment: It could be the shell from which you launch Elixir is only informed of LC_TIME on start up and its env vars  don't get informed of any subsequent changes. In that case you might need to launch a new shell from within Elixir and then somehow scrape its env vars.  But this is just my guess.

Answer (score 1):

In "core Elixir" there is no such functionality, as Elixir/Erlang do not ship with locales data nor it provides API to use system data. Instead you need to fetch [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/index) data on your own and use that, fortunately there is [`ex_cldr`](https://github.com/kipcole9/cldr) library that does that for you. In addition there is extension [`ex_cldr_date_times`](https://hex.pm/packages/ex_cldr_dates_times) that supports formatting dates. So in the end, when you install both of these libraries you can use:

```
Cldr.DateTime.to_string(DateTime.utc_now)
```

To receive localized string in current locale.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `DateTime.utc_now` and then format date you want:

```
iex(5)> d = DateTime.utc_now  
#DateTime<2019-05-16 15:01:51.662814Z>
iex(6)> DateTime.to_string(d)
"2019-05-16 15:01:51.662814Z"
iex(7)> s = "#{d.year}/#{d.month}/#{d.day}"
"2019/5/16"
```

Or you can get the data format from `:calendar.local_time` like below and then print it into everything you want:

```
iex(12)> {{y, m, d},_} =  :calendar.local_time()
{{2019, 5, 16}, {22, 4, 29}}
iex(13)> y
2019
iex(14)> m
5
iex(15)> d
16
```

Comment: @bxdoan Unfortunately this was not the question I asked. I can get the day, month year. I just need to know if it should be displayed in dd/mmyy or mm/dd/yy format!