# date-fns - is there a way to get short date format string

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I'm using date-fns and trying to figure out how to get date format string from locales.
E.g. when using en-US locale I'd like to get 'MM/dd/yyyy' as the result.

I found this answer [Get Locale Short Date Format using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388115/get-locale-short-date-format-using-javascript) but it seems redundant to write own function for that as date-fns locales already contain such string...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, reading date-fns source code answered my question:

```
import { enGB } from 'date-fns/locale';
let formatString = enGB.formatLong.date({width:"short"});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var dateFns = require("date-fns")
var locale = require("date-fns/locale")

dateFns.format(new Date(), 'P', { locale: locale.enGB }) // 29/01/2020
dateFns.format(new Date(), 'P', { locale: locale.en })   // 01/29/2020
```

You will still need to create a mapping from locale string to date-fns locale modules as recommended by their documentation https://date-fns.org/v1.9.0/docs/I18n

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Intl` object of javascript with `DateTimeFormat`:

```js
let date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language).format(new Date());

console.log(date)
```