# Vue js change attribute date format

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an object in vue js retrieved from form with attribute date and a value 22-02-2022. How can I change this value to be 2022-02-22?

Comment: [Old question on SO with solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388115/get-locale-short-date-format-using-javascript) , 
[JS Intl object formatting methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

Comment: What kind of form, under which regional settings and what kind of conversion, i.e. where (client/backend)? Your question lacks context.

Answer (score 0):

I use moment.js. Here's an example. I usually put it on computed (U can put it as method and use some parameters to make it more flexible).

```
dateFormat() {
  return moment(this.yourObject.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with an input with attribute date and the value om getting is already in yyyy-mm-dd format

```
  <input type="date" class="form-control" v-model="birthdate" />
```

But you can perform the conversion yourself to fit your requirement with below example

```
  watch:{
birthdate: function(){
  console.log("Value from input "+this.birthdate)
  let tempArr = this.birthdate.split("-")
  let formattedDate = tempArr[2]+"-"+tempArr[1]+"-"+tempArr[0]
  console.log("Formatted: "+formattedDate)
}}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can turn value into array and reverse them

```
let str = '22-02-2022'.split("-").reverse().join("-");
console.log(str);
```