# Is there anyway to detect OS language using javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I need to detect OS language using javascript so I can view my page depending on the language.

I know that we can detect the browser language but that is not enough for me.

I need Operation System language

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't do it.  You can have your user explicitly select a language, or you can obey the language(s) listed in the "Accept-Language" header.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no cross-browser way to do this. Internet Explorer supports the following:

- `navigator.browserLanguage`: browser language
- `navigator.systemLanguage`: Windows system language
- `navigator.userLanguage`: Windows user-specific language

But there is no way to access these settings from any other browsers (that I can tell) so *don't use them*: stick to the standard `navigator.language` (corresponding to the browser language) if you want to maintain cross-browser functionality. If you do use them you will tie your web site to a specific family of operating systems (i.e. Windows) and a specific browser (i.e. Internet Explorer). Do you really want to do this?

Why is the browser language insufficient for your application?

Comment: I am looking for navigator.systemLanguage , can I use it with firefox or just IE??

Comment: No, IE only I'm afraid. However, this stuff is complicated. However, I think you should think long and hard about why the browser's language is not sufficient.

Comment: @SzamDev: Firefox provides `navigator.language`, which is much the same thing, see Matthew's answer.

Comment: @T.J. `navigator.language` is equivalent to `navigator.browserLanguage`.

Comment: about your question, Why is the browser language insufficient for your application? I have pages for each language, I want after detect the OS language to redirect to this page or display it because sometime the browser language maybe not the same of OS

Comment: @SzamDev: That's your user's problem, not yours. If they're lying to you, well, they should fix that. You're dealing with the browser, so that's the language you should be dealing with.

Answer (score 21):

This returns the system language:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale
```

Comment: Why the heck this isn't the right answer? It works perfectly in the main browsers. I tested in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer (Microsoft Edge).

Comment: The question was asked 12 years ago, so that's a thing. I'm interested in seeing if Stack Overflow ever gets better at changing answers over time.

Comment: this is getting browser's language setting, not OS's

Answer (score 5):

You **may** just **guess** OS **language** considering few factors:

## Windows OS

### Internet Explorer

- `navigator.browserLanguage`: IE language (menu, help and etc.), the same as OS display language (if user hasn't change it). As in Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Keyboards and Lanugages -> Display language
- `navigator.systemLanguage`: as in Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Location
- `navigator.userLanguage`: as in Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Formats

### ECMAScript Internationalization API

```
var d=new Date(Date.UTC(2014,1,26,3,0,0));
var dateFormat={weekday:"long",year:"numeric",month:"long",day:"numeric"};
var result = d.toLocaleDateString("i-default",dateFormat);
alert(result);
//e.g. for Russian format ( Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Formats ) 
//result == 'среда, 26 февраля 2014 г.'
```

Then search `result` on your server over preliminary generated set of formatted dates in different languages.

*NB!* Chrome returns date formatted in its UI language.

### Adobe Flash

If you desperately need to know OS language — embed **flash** in your page and exploit [flash.system.Capabilities.language](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#language):

*NB!* **Chrome doesn't allow the trick** — Chrome's Flash always shows `browser.language`, I think because it has own Flash.

### Firefox and Chrome

`navigator.language` tells you a browser's UI language (menu, help and etc.) and you **may** assume that in overwhelming majority of cases it matches OS language (especially for home computers): while downloading FF or Chrome a download page is displayed according user's then browser — on Windows it is IE in the same language as OS.

*It is very strange indeed that Chrome is thing in itself when dealing with browser's environment parameters, alas.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use the user agent.  However, it can be spoofed easily, it is not guaranteed to contain language information, and `navigator.language` and `navigator.browserLanguage` will probably be more reliable.

Comment: He's talking about the locale, I think.

Comment: `navigator.language` or `navigator.browserLanguage`, it's never been standardized: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Navigator.language, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533542(v=VS.85).aspx IE also provides `systemLanguage` and `userLanguage`

Answer (score 2):

You can get from the js with default languages, and supported languages through this:

`navigator.language`

Return ***'en-GB'***

`navigator.languages`

Returns ***['en-GB', 'en-US', 'en', 'zh-CN']***

PS: I tested on Chrome on Windows (Not sure if Mac also works the same)

Comment: Yes, it should work fine on most platforms.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/language

Answer (score 1):

One thing for everyone here to consider, not all users know how to set their browser language preferences.  So if you're making a site you WANT people to see, it's your problem if they land on it in a different language than one they're comfortable with, as it increases the change they will leave.  A lot of it depends on the demographic you're targeting, but for a web page I think it's good to detect the system language IF you can at least, then then fall back on the browser language if you can't.  It's more likely to be accurate.

Comment: (until looking for this setting, as an english speaker never having the need, i had no idea how to change it.  which could really be a pain for me on vacation at an itallian coffee shop, even if i had used the language bar to change the system language.)