# PHP get current client OS language

Tags: php, language-detection

I wanted to know, is there any way from PHP/javascript to get current client OS language. I tried to use `$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]` but sometimes it get the wrong language.
For example in Google Chrome:

1. My OS: Windows 7
2. Language: English

Using `$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]` I got this result:

```
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: zh,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

It said "zh" is my primary language.

Is there any other way to get client OS language? Because that's what I wanted, not the browser language setting. Thanks

Comment: `zh` is because your browser has detected that you live in that country and hence you should recieve that language as your primary language. Chrome does this to help the users as much as possible (includes google search results, they will be based on a major city near you.. mine is Stockholm and i don't even live near.. and yes i'm well awware that it's a lot of geo-detection on a IP/Hostname basis but that's the baseline of the functionality)

Comment: *It said "zh" is my primary language.* — No, it doesn't. Since `zh` doesn't have an explicit quality value, it has a quality of `1.0`. This is the same quality as `en-US`, therefore `zh` and `en-US` have equal weights.

Comment: @Quentin is right. Perhaps you could get something from user agent string.

Comment: HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31, doesn't help much. But if zh,en-US;q=0.8 have equal weights it's difficult to choose. Since I wanted to get client OS language not the browser language setting is there any other way?

Answer (score 4):

try this function

```
function getUserLanguage() {
 $langs = array();
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
// break up string into pieces (languages and q factors)
preg_match_all('/([a-z]{1,8}(-[a-z]{1,8})?)\s*(;\s*q\s*=\s*(1|0\.[0-9]+))?/i',
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], $lang_parse);
if (count($lang_parse[1])) {
// create a list like â??enâ?? => 0.8
$langs = array_combine($lang_parse[1], $lang_parse[4]);
// set default to 1 for any without q factor
foreach ($langs as $lang => $val) {
if ($val === '') $langs[$lang] = 1;
}
// sort list based on value
arsort($langs, SORT_NUMERIC);
}
}
//extract most important (first)
foreach ($langs as $lang => $val) { break; }
//if complex language simplify it
if (stristr($lang,"-")) {$tmp = explode("-",$lang); $lang = $tmp[0]; }
return $lang;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Send it via javascript on IE?

- `navigator.browserLanguage`: browser language
- `navigator.systemLanguage`: Windows system language
- `navigator.userLanguage`: Windows user-specific language

Thanks to: [Is there anyway to detect OS language using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894488/is-there-anyway-to-detect-os-language-using-javascript)

That's the only way besides the one you've mentioned to get the language of the **client** OS, PHP is run by the server and nothing else.

Build a PHP sorting function.

```
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: zh,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

`zh` and `en-US` share the same `q=` value, meaning that you can sort on the highest language value and default to en-US if the quality is the same on two languages.

Just noticed that @Quentin mentioned this in the comment section a minute before my edit, well done sir!

Mockup:

```
$languages = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
$default = 'en-US';
/*
 * magic split and structure the language into a array sorted by quality
 *
 * $languages_sorted_by_quality = array(0.8 => ('zh', 'en-US'));
 */
$top_languages = max($languages_sorted_by_quality);
if (isset($top_languages[$default])) {
    $language = $default;
else
    $language = $top_languages[0];
```

Comment: This is available only in IE.
As far as I know, there is no way to identify OS language that work under all major browsers.

Comment: Correct, should probably mentioned that. You'd have to make a sort function on `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`.

Answer (score 0):

have your tried [http_negotiate_language](https://www.php.net/http_negotiate_language)

Comment: Warning: As far as I remember, that PHP function is poorly implemented and has some poorly results.

Comment: not sure about implementation being poor but the only comment which has a function is well done.