# Localization for Tumblr blog posts?

Tags: localization, blogs, tumblr

Is there something like [qTranslate for Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/) for [Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com) so I can localize blog posts? I need to write posts in English and German so that the German posts show up for German readers and English for the rest. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the first part of your question, “Is there something like qTranslate for Wordpress for Tumblr” is no: Tumblr is not a (quasi-)CMS system like WordPress. What you get in the [Tumblr theme docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes) is all there is as to customization.

The answer to part two is: you can cook up anything you feel like using the tools Tumblr offers in its theme customization toolkit, which would be HTML, CSS and JavaScript (which, unlike hosted WordPress, is **not** blocked in the theme), but it is up to you. If the text exists in a translated form for both languages, the basic approach would be to include both versions in the page, give it the correct [`lang` attribute](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/lang) and style your CSS to hide one by default (using the `[lang="x"]` attribute selector), then use JavaScript to guess at the visitors’s locale (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673905/best-way-to-determine-users-locale-within-browser) for some pointers) or offer a selection mechanism and toggle the hidden status of the two blocks (trivial with jQuery).

Finally, Tumblr’s theme templating language is localization aware – check out [the localization section of the docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/localizing_themes) for how to localize the theme itself (not the content).