# Jquery DatePicker: how set date format according to system date format

Tags: jquery, date

The default format of jquery datepicker is [MM/dd/yy].Even if i change the system date format like [dd/MM/yyy] datepicker takes a default format  i.e [MM-dd-yy]. How to set datepicker format according to system datetime format.

Please help me....

Comment: Are you using [jquery ui datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)? You can set the date format using the [dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) property. The problem is, how do you detect the system datetime format using javascript?

Comment: Exactly to the point,in jquery dateformat is defaultly set to MM-dd-yy format.How to detect the system datetime format using javascript

Comment: you can get the date and validate it with some typical date format.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, the only hint at the used locale seems to be `navigator.language`, according to [Best way to determine user's locale within browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673905/1741542). From [Datepicker Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) (search for Localization), you can then use something like

```
$(selector).datepicker($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
```

It would be easier to determine the preferred locale from server side, evaluating [`Accept-Language`](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Negotiation) and send a customized JS file.

There are also examples at [Format date](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats) and [Localize calendar](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization), which lets users pick their preferred format.