# MooTools Date Picker default format

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, timezone, mootools

I am using the datepicker from mootools and trying to have it localised format depending on the users location.

For example:

```
08/15/13 //American
15.08.13 //English
```

The documentation states that it should change by default `format: (*string*, defaults to the default localized format)`

But using this code:

```
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    new Picker.Date($$('input'), {
        timePicker: true,
        positionOffset: {x: 5, y: 0},
        pickerClass: 'datepicker_bootstrap',
        useFadeInOut: !Browser.ie
    });
});
```

It always uses the American format `08/15/13` (Month first).

I am testing by changing my Time Zone set in windows 7 `Date and Time`

Comment: date picker (if the one by arian) uses `Locale` from mootools-more. try `Locale.use()` and read the documentation http://mootools.net/docs/more/Locale/Locale

Comment: Thanks for the pointer... Although I must admit, I thought default meant it would do this out of the box? No? I'm happy though to play around and try and use `Locale.use()` and output it as a string for the `Picker`

Comment: Still haven't found a solid solution to this

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think DatePicker does that "out of the box". I am not sure there is a water-proof way to get user location or language codes in client side scripts.

I just tried :

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
console.log(language);
```

and got `"sv"` in Chrome and `"en-GB"` in Firefox, in the same machine.

I got about the same using php / HTTP-request header. Thought about getting the info from server-side. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673905/best-way-to-determine-users-locale-within-browser) question points `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` as the best way, BUT:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] // gives me:
sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4 //in chrome
en-gb,en;q=0.5 //in firefox
```

If you look in the DatePicker.js file you have in the first lines:

```
---
name: Locale.en-US.DatePicker
description: English Language File for DatePicker
authors: Arian Stolwijk
requires: [More/Locale]
provides: Locale.en-US.DatePicker
...
```

This gives me a feeling that it is set to en-US. It will work if you set it manually though.

My suggestion is to follow [Dimitar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126998/dimitar-christoff)'s suggestion and set it manually with Locale.use(). If you add for example `Locale.use('sv-SE');` before you call DatePicker you will get date in format yyyy-mm-dd.

I did a script to read the client-side language to try to make it dynamical. It works but It's not tested. This assigns a language comparing the Mootools `Locale.list()` and the browser/javascript answer I posted above:

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
console.log(language); //gives the results I wrote above (sv/en-GB resp. Chrome/FF)
var list = Locale.list().length;
for (var i = 0; i < list; i++) {
    if (Locale.list()[i] == language) { //check if it's a full match
        Locale.use(language);
    } else { 
// go for the first part of the "sv-SE" and find a match
// this is a compromise, it gets the right language but might miss the right country
        var langArray = language.split('-');
        var locArray = Locale.list()[i].split('-');
        for (var k = 0; k < list; k++) {
            if (langArray[0] == locArray[0]) {
                Locale.use(Locale.list()[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(Locale.getCurrent().name); // gives sv-SE/en-GB resp. Chrome/FF
new Picker.Date($$('input'), { 
// etc...
```

If you thinks it's useful you can fine-tune it...
**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/r7Qsk/)**

Comment: I got intrigued about a way to find the location client-side that could be used in Locale.use(), so i asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680413/get-visitors-language-country-code-with-javascript-client-side) about it, in case there is a modern solution for this.