# Cloudfront/S3: Server different file depending on Request Header

Tags: localization, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, middleman

I am hosting a static website generated with Middleman on CloudFront and S3. I want to add multiple language support and middleman allows me to localize the content and have the english version at /index.html and the translated content at /sp/index.html for example.

I would like to be able to detect the "Accept-Language" header in the request and based on that server either /index.html or /sp/index.html .

Based on my research I cannot see a way of doing this with S3 and Cloudfront, but maybe you guys have an idea?

If there is no "proper and good way" of doing this with CloudFront and S3, what would be the next best alternative? Currently I am thinking of detecting the language in JavaScript and then redirecting the user if the language is not english.

Greetings, Kim

Comment: you can setup a proxy server in front of the bucket and add rewrite conditions

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments you will need some kind of arbitrator that can read request headers and either redirect or serve dynamic content. S3 is the problem there.

CloudFront can [forward the Accept-Language header to your origin server](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html), and ensure that content is only cached per-language. So that part isn't a problem.

If S3 is your origin, then you have a problem because your files are static and unable to process the incoming request with the language information. I don't recommend trying to detect language with JavaScript. [It's problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680413/get-visitors-language-country-code-with-javascript-client-side/17696328).

Although CloudFront can be configured with multiple origins (one per language, in your case) it cannot forward to these based on request header. Currently "behaviours" can only match the URL path. I suspect they could introduce header rules at some point, but until they do (or unless you can find another CDN that does) I'm afraid my answer is going to be a "you can't" answer.

As your site is all flat HTML, I suspect you're not interested in a convoluted solution that comprises various CloudFront behaviours and dynamic server scripts, etc..

I think your best option by far is a simple, low-tech one --

Offer the visitor a choice of language and allow them to switch language from any page. This also avoids surprises - If I google something in English, but I speak Spanish I should see the English page that I googled and then switch to Spanish if I feel like it.