# Get url parameters and redirect to specific url with javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

How can I redirect to specific url that appear in the url parameter?

example:

http://www.mywebsite.com/Code_id.tv/stream.php

I want to get code_id and I will redirect to specific URL.

The result URL will eventually look like this:

http://www.mynewwebsite.com/tv.php?id=Code_id

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split the path to get the code_id:

```
var url2Process = window.location.pathname;
var patharray = url2Process.split( '/' );

// remove '.tv' or '.movie' or '.whatever' from the end
var code_id_array = patharray[1].split('.');
var code_id = code_id_array[0];

// redirect
window.location = 'http://domain.com/rb/play.php?id=tt' + code_id;
```

Comment: How to redirect with specific ip address country ?
example : I want to redirect if US country visitor only

Comment: Make an ajax call client side to this http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php and it returns what country the user is in

Comment: my knowledge about api and javascript is not enough :( I hope you can give me sample code :)

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680413/get-visitors-language-country-code-with-javascript-client-side then just use result.countrycode to test if it is equal to `US` `$.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json', function(result) {
    alert(result.country_code);
  });`