# Get User Country Code (e.g. 'GB') Client Side (locally) PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Is there any way to get  a user Country code from a client side (locally)? So far, I have tried the code in this link; https://stackoverflow.com/a/13600004/5947201 but I believe that this code is server side and won't work locally. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680413/get-visitors-language-country-code-with-javascript-client-side says no, and it says it pretty clearly. Check it out.

Comment: You can get the current position (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) and use the coordinates to determine the country

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use any web API You can use [GeoIP2-php](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php) web services and database reader to get users location . you have to [download](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) free GeoLite2 databases or any mmdb database can GeoIP2-php read .

**Installation (via Phar)** - easy way

download phar archive from GeoIP2 Github [releases](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php/releases) then include it to your project

```
require 'geoip2.phar';

use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

$reader = new Reader('GeoLite2-City.mmdb');

$record = $reader->city('128.101.101.101');

print($record->country->isoCode . "\n"); // 'US'
print($record->country->name . "\n"); // 'United States'
```

Comment: I've tried this but how can I get the country from the IP? I've tried your code and it displayed 'US' but I am not from US..

Comment: you have to change 128.101.101.101 to your ip