# Laravel get user language based on user country

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multilingual

i trying to set the user default language based on user's country

i tried to use this command

```
Request::server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE');
```

but it give me this result:

```
en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.4,zh;q=0.2,ru;q=0.2
```

so i realized that this is not the right way to detect the user default language because it based on the browser usage and i think that my users will prefer to use their country language

so i wonder what is the best way to get the user language based on his country?

thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get visitors language & country code with javascript (client-side)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680413/get-visitors-language-country-code-with-javascript-client-side)

Comment: Kev thank you this is a nice solutions, i'm bit afraid to use http://freegeoip.net/json/ service cause i cant be sure that they will always be active and i also dont get the main language of the country but only the country name, country code etc...

Comment: We tend to use ACCEPT_LANGUAGE header (with the `mcamara/laravel-localization` package). It is most often OK, IP could be better but it's a lot harder to implement.

Comment: Also, ACCEPT_LANGUAGE is set by the user's browser, so there's a lot more chances to get the right language for this user (i.e. a user who is on a trip doesn't necessarily want to display the website in the local language).

Comment: Using a language based on the location of a person is a very bad idea. People do not necessarily speak the main language of the place where they currently reside. And there are places that have no distinct main language (Switzerland, Canada, ...)