# Next.JS set url path based on user location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have website in Next JS which has the domain abc.com
what I want is when someone visit to my website
my website will check the location of the user and get the country code
then it will rewrite my URL to abc.com/country_code

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680413/get-visitors-language-country-code-with-javascript-client-side

Answer (score 0):

You could use built in middleware (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware
)
and rewrite (return NextResponse.rewrite(…)) based on a location mapping.

This could be got via API from e.g. Google Maps

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation