# Javascript users incorrect locale with date formatting

Tags: javascript, date, locale, date-format

In javascript I'm using `Date.toLocaleDateString` to format my dates in the user's locale.  While in theory it should work, it doesn't.

I am located in the UK.  My computer is set to UK and my default language is set to en/gb in both system settings and the browser content settings.  Yet, Firefox always displays dates the US format.  Is there some trick I'm missing?

The full code for formatting is this:

```
var timestamp = ...; //some value from ajax call
var dt = new Date(timestamp);
$('#audit-date').text(dt.toLocaleDateString());
```

In the UK for today's date I would expect to see `05/02/2014`, but I see `02/05/2014`, which is the US version of it.

Comment: I use _Chrome_, my _Windows_ machine region is set to _UK/England/London_, `toLocaleDateString` gives me US style dates. I think it's because we speak _English_ so just download the default _en-US_ version of the browser. I usually write dates in an international way which is unmistakable, for example `2014-02-05` for today.

Comment: What does `(new Date()).toLocaleDateString()` give?

Comment: I'm also having this issue, On two machines in our office one returns `toLocaleDateString` the US way the other the UK way. I tried `toLocaleDateString(window.navigator.language)`. But it just flips the problem as on the one returning the UK date it returns its language as "en-US" which makes no sense!! what is it based on?

Answer (score 6):

Use this to pass the locale.

```
var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
alert(date.toLocaleString(locale));
```

Answer (score 4):

A quick look into to awesome MDN Documentation tells me that you need a locale parameter, otherwise the result depends on the browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

```
// British English uses day-month-year order
alert(date.toLocaleString("en-GB"));
// → "20/12/2012 03:00:00"
```

For more custom date formats I use the moment.js library. http://momentjs.com/

Comment: This defeats the purpose.  I don't know what the locale is - I want the to automatically match user's locale.

Comment: You said your computers locale is UK/GB but your browsers is probably not. It's also possible that JavaScripts hat no possibility to get you locale further than the language, as this post suggests. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673905/best-way-to-determine-users-locale-within-browser