# NextJs 13 (i18n) Incorrect locale information provided

Tags: javascript, http, next.js13

I have been trying to use the NextJs [i18n  routing on a website](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization) [Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230610190155/https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization), but when I followed the exact steps provided in the documentation, I got this error: Incorrect locale information provided

I tried to debug it by checking the headers of the requests but it's all correct.

I tried to solve this by checking the error on console, reading related questions on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589401/javascript-users-incorrect-locale-with-date-formatting) [Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230610190202/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589401/javascript-users-incorrect-locale-with-date-formatting) and [GitHub](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/discussions/2440)  [Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230610190208/https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/discussions/2440) but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is happening due to getting the language array as: [ "*" ]
Which is not defined in the language that we have,  I added an if condition to solve this issue:

```js
    if (languages.length === 1 && languages[0] === '*') {
        languages = ['ar']
    }
```

Then followed the same steps in the documentation and it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on my middleware.ts and the issue is solved now:

```
const locales: string[] = i18n.locales;
  let languages = new Negotiator({ headers: negotiatorHeaders }).languages();
  if (languages.length === 1 && languages[0] === "*") {
    languages = ["en"];
  }
```

Comment: what's the point of this answer? does it elaborate on the other answer in any meaningful way? or is it just to say thanks?

Comment: You can take it as both. I've thanked him and also I've shared the detailed solution of the problem with the file where the code needs to be added.