# Detecting users locale for dates with angular/momentjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, localization, internationalization

I have used angular date filter to format and display dates in `medium` format. However, how can I automatically detect what locale user have and configure angular to display the correct date format for that particular Country and language? User will not be able to change language in the application, only through configurations in browser (I guess). So its ok to refresh in order to reflect the changes.

Im also using momentjs for other date-functions, but has not used it for this purpose. Maybe I should?

The frontend application is served by nodejs and REST services are used between these two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to determine user's locale within browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673905/best-way-to-determine-users-locale-within-browser)

Comment: That post is 5 years old, but it might be that we have not come any longer on this topic since then?!

Comment: How can timezone module help me detecting what locale current user has?

Comment: Oh, sorry LOL, totally read that wrong! I don't know a good answer. In the last international app I worked on we had a language selector in the app and did not even look at headers etc. I suspect header inspection will be the most effective thing right now though.

Comment: Moment timezone won't help. Accept-Language headers are still the way to go.