# Get current locale of Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, locale

I am determining the current locale of the browser using this API:

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
```

This return `"fr-FR"` in IE, but it returns just `"fr"` in Chrome (and similarly for other locales).

Is there another API that will return `"fr-FR"` in Chrome as well?

We rely on this to load the appropriate culture files.

Comment: Just as a tip, if you're planning to rely on this information to actually figure out the user locale, I wouldn't recommend it. Most of the users never change this setting, so it'll probably find `en-US`, which is the default value.

Comment: Please answer on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to determine user's locale within browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673905/best-way-to-determine-users-locale-within-browser)

Answer (score 24):

Update:

As of Sept 2021 Chrome has pretty extensive support for the `Intl` library.

```js
function getClientLocale() {
  if (typeof Intl !== 'undefined') {
    try {
      return Intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions().locale;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Cannot get locale from Intl")
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise you can fallback to the `window.navigator` object:

Firefox and Chrome have a `languages` array on the `navigator` object. Normally the first element in that array is the users chosen locale (normally inherited from the OS settings)

```
var language;
if (window.navigator.languages) {
    language = window.navigator.languages[0];
} else {
    language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
}
```

The `navigator.languages` array in chrome for me is `["en-GB", "en-US", "en"]` whereas `navigator.language = "en-US"`, slightly different but important

Comment: This question was about getting the locale, not only the language. A locale contains much more information than only the language (most importantly date-time and number-formatting settings).

Comment: @exhuma, maybe so, but it's apparent that the OP asked about the locale string

Comment: @exhuma, you don't pass around the entire locale pack.  It's just the locale id, usually the Unicode one, that gets passed around (e.g. `en-GB`).  See W3's doc: https://www.w3.org/TR/ltli/#locale and MDN's: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale to consume, you can pass that ID to `.toLocaleString()` of different objects, like `Date`.

Comment: Other `Intl` constructors work as well, e.g. `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale` or `Intl.Collator().resolvedOptions().locale`.

Comment: For me here in AU ``getClientLocale()`` returns 'en-US'. Whereas the navigator. version returns 'en-AU'

Comment: On the same machine, in Chrome `getClientLocale()` returns 'en-US' while the same function in Firefox returns 'en-CA'.

Answer (score 6):

In the latest versions of Chrome browser, 
it `var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;` returns 'fr-FR'.

If you are still facing the same issue, you can try `var language = navigator.language;`

Comment: This returns strictly the user language, but **not** their locale. For instance, i have a browser setting where all of the above return `de-DE`, whilst `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale` returns `en-US`. So, sorry to say, but this answer does not help the OPs question.