# How to detect language fonts are supported or not in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I do not have that much knowledge in `mobile O.S.I` have developed an web application that shows indian language characters. it is working fine in web browsers but I am finding some issues in mobile browsers.I came to know that it is called `rendering issue`. My purpose is not to solve this issue but I just want to show the users like `"x,y,z language is not supported by your device"` like this. Basically I want to write a `js file` that will load and will display this as an alert. But I am finding it difficult to to write js code that will interact with mob and will give some alert.
I have not attached any code as I am clueless.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/674570/1059101 this might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));

if(mobile)
{
    alert("MOBILE DEVICE DETECTED");
}
else
{
    alert("BROWSER DETECTED");
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.