# Momentjs - set locale from the user time

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I want to set the moment.locale according to the user country by looking at the browser or timestamp or something. 
Not sure how this could be achieved.

currently i am achieving like this -

```
const userLocale = 'ja';
moment.locale(userLocale);
```

any ideas awesome folks?

Comment: You can find infos about getting browser's locale [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/673905/4131048) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1043339/4131048)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

However, dates in JavaScript always defaults to the user's local timezone. So it sounds like a problem that is solved by default. For example, by running the snippet below I see my local time, which is GMT-0500. You should see something different if you're in another timezone.

But if you want to convert a local timestamp to a specific timezone from a user setting or similar, moment-timezone is the easiest way.

```js
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = new Date();
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```

Comment: Nice! but bit tricky though.I have to map it through and find the right locale, doable.

Comment: @GeekOnGadgets you can try `moment.tz.guess();`

Answer (score 0):

You can get Browser's locale by

```
var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
```

and use that locale to set Moment's locale

```
moment.locale(locale);
```

If there's a problem in getting browser's locale try

```
var locale = navigator.languages && navigator.languages[0] || // Chrome and Firefox
           navigator.language ||   // All browsers
           navigator.userLanguage; // IE <= 10
```

Hope it helps :)