# How to get selected locale in custom field type?

Tags: storyblok

I'm trying to build custom field type / plugin in Storyblok according to their [guide](https://www.storyblok.com/docs/plugins) and need to get selected `locale` or current `slug` at least. I don't see such information in Vuejs instance of that plugin. Can anyone advise on it and provide some code how to do it?

Comment: would https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673905/best-way-to-determine-users-locale-within-browser help?

Answer (score 0):

This information can now be accessed by the new attribute this.storyItem