# Browser Language. Weird Behaviour - Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, localization

I have tested with different people and from my understanding the best way to determine the language for my site on Internet Explorer is by using `systemLanguage`

But I have found an issue.

One of the testers has this languages in the Internet Options

[image: Please see this]

The default language is English (the first), which is correct but the browser detects the second language and get's the German.

[image: Please see this]

Can someone explain me how do I retrieve the default (first) language from that list? Why IE displays German instead of English? At least it should be an array.

My code:

```
 var lang = window.navigator.systemLanguage || window.navigator.language;
    if (lang.indexOf('-') !== -1) {
        lang = lang.substr(0, lang.indexOf('-'));
    }
```

Comment: https://zzz.buzz/2016/01/13/detect-browser-language-in-javascript/

Comment: I'm in favor of pqnet's answer. I think the standard way is to use `navigator.language`. As mentioned in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language) and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_language.asp), this property returns *the language of the browser UI* and *get the language of your browser*. For more information, you could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673905/best-way-to-determine-users-locale-within-browser).

Answer (score 3):

`systemLanguage` is a IE-only api that *returns the language edition of the operating system*. Don't read it, rely on `window.navigator.language` which is standard

Comment: This only works if you're targeting later version then IE11. If you need to support earlier IE version then `navigator.language` wont work.

Comment: you should rely on polyfills when targeting older browser versions. See https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills .
If you're still into cooking your own IE language detection code, go for `browserLanguage` or `userLanguage`

Comment: also, Microsoft is ending support for IE10 in january, so you may not worry too much about supporting that browser:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4488955/support-ending-for-internet-explorer-10