# How to detect the best locale based on the browser language settings?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to find the best locale supported by my web application for a given user.

For example, my application supports the locales `en_GB` and `es_MX` and the browser supports `fr` and `en_US`. In that case the user would want to see `en_GB`.

I have used the [`locale`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/locale) package before, which does exactly that, but it only works on the server-side as it uses the `Accept-Language` header.

How can I do this using [`navigator.languages`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/674570/4136777) in the browser?

Comment: There's a lot of advice about this already on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.  Why can't you make it work?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I haven’t been able to find any resources for this exact use case. If you did, please share it with me