# Adyen: Possible to localize payment method name

Tags: reactjs, locale, adyen

I would like to know if it is possible to config the payment method name (in adyen-checkout__payment-method__header) based on the locale.

eg: Instead of "credit card", payment method name shows "carte bancaire" if locale is "fr_FR". Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOeMP.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The Adyen Drop-In and components do support localization, [as described here].[1](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in/customization#language-and-localization).

You would have to pass the locale in the configuration object when initializing the Drop-in.

This is how it looks like for French :

```
const configuration = {
    locale: "fr-FR",
    ...
};
```

Finding out which locale to use may depend on your implementation, user choices or browser settings. [Here is an answer with more information about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673905/how-to-determine-users-locale-within-browser).

If needed, you can also decide to customize a given localization, the procedure is described [here](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in/customization#customizing-a-localization).